# Mollweide maps in Mathematica

Tags: graphics, image-processing, astronomy, projection

**Context**

In my field of research, many people use the following package: [healpix](http://healpix.jpl.nasa.gov) (for  Hierarchical Equal Area isoLatitude Pixelization)
which has been ported to a few different languages (F90, C,C++, Octave, Python, IDL, MATLAB, Yorick, to name a few). It is used to operate on the sphere and its tangent space and implements amongst other things fast (possibly spinned) harmonic transform, equal area sampling, etc.

In the long run, I feel it would be useful for our community to be able to have this functionality as well.

As a starting point, I am interested in producing [Mollweide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollweide_projection) maps in Mathematica.
My purpose is to be able to do maps such as

[image: Mollweide projection of the Milky Way]

which (for those interested) represents our Milky Way (in purple) on top of the the cosmic microwave background (in red, the afterglow of the Big Bang) seen by the [Planck satellite](http://www.esa.int/SPECIALS/Planck/index.html).

**Attempt**

Thanks to halirutan's head start, this is what I have so far:

```
cart[{lambda_, phi_}] := With[{theta = fc[phi]}, {2 /Pi*lambda Cos[theta], Sin[theta]}]
fc[phi_] := Block[{theta}, If[Abs[phi] == Pi/2, phi, theta /. 
 FindRoot[2 theta + Sin[2 theta] == Pi Sin[phi], {theta, phi}]]];
```

which basically allows me to do plots like

```
grid = With[{delta = Pi/18/2},
            Table[{lambda, phi}, {phi, -Pi/2, Pi/2, delta}, {lambda, -Pi, Pi, delta}]];
gr1 = Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[0.05], Line /@ grid, Line /@ Transpose[grid]},
               AspectRatio -> 1/2];
gr0 = Flatten[{gr1[[1, 2]][[Range[9]*4 - 1]],gr1[[1, 3]][[Range[18]*4 - 3]]}] // 
Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[0.2], #}] &;
gr2 = Table[{Hue[t/Pi], Point[{ t , t/2}]}, {t, -Pi, Pi, 1/100}] // 
Flatten // Graphics;
gr = Show[{gr1, gr0, gr2}, Axes -> True]
```

[image: initial image]

```
gr /. Line[pts_] :> Line[cart /@ pts] /. Point[pts_] :> Point[cart[ pts]]
```

and project them to a Mollweide representation

[image: Mollweide projection of initial image]

**Question**

Starting from an image like this one:
[image: spherical Perlin noise, equirectangular projection]

(which some of you will recognize;-))

I would like to produce its Mollweide view.

Note that `WorldPlot` has this projection.

In the long run, I am wondering how to link (via MathLink?) to existing F90/C routines for fast harmonic transforms available in [healpix](http://healpix.jpl.nasa.gov).

Comment: Perhaps we should host the image on imgur instead of directly embedding it from tpfto.files.wordpress.com, because (i) hotlinking is bad, and (ii) the site could change its URLs or take the image down.

Comment: @RahulNarain I fixed this. This image was produced by J.M.

Comment: P.S. that spherical Perlin noise image you linked to is indeed an equirectangular projection. :)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Transform an image under an arbitrary projection? Looks like a job for `ImageTransformation` :)

@halirutan's `cart` function gives you a mapping from latitude and longitude to the Mollweide projection. What we need here is the inverse mapping, because `ImageTransformation` is going to look at each pixel in the Mollweide projection and fill it in with the colour of the corresponding pixel in the original image. Fortunately [MathWorld has us covered](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MollweideProjection.html):

> $$\begin{align}
> \phi &= \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2\theta+\sin2\theta}\pi\right), \\
> \lambda &= \lambda_0 + \frac{\pi x}{2\sqrt2\cos\theta},
> \end{align}$$
>   where
>   $$\theta=\sin^{-1}\frac y{\sqrt2}.$$

Here $x$ and $y$ are the coordinates in the Mollweide projection, and $\phi$ and $\lambda$ are the latitude and longitude respectively. The projection is off by a factor of $\sqrt2$ compared to the `cart` function, so for consistency I'll omit the $\sqrt2$'s in my implementation. I'll also assume that the central longitude, $\lambda_0$, is zero.

```
invmollweide[{x_, y_}] := 
 With[{theta = ArcSin[y]}, {Pi x/(2 Cos[theta]), 
   ArcSin[(2 theta + Sin[2 theta])/Pi]}]
```

Now we just apply this to our original equirectangular image, where $x$ is longitude and $y$ is latitude, to get the Mollweide projection.

```
i = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xyhd.png"]

ImageTransformation[i, invmollweide, 
 DataRange -> {{-Pi, Pi}, {-Pi/2, Pi/2}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image]

Comment: that pretty much nails it. I thought ImageTransformation only did translation/rotation. Thanks...

Comment: would you know how to set up the background to white (just to be perfectionist)?

Comment: That seems to be the `Padding` option. Try `Padding -> White`.

Comment: @RahulHarain would you know how to superpose your plot and mine (i.e. the mollweide image and the gridline)? I tried for about 1h... ;-(

Comment: I'm afraid not. You could ask a new question.

Comment: @chris `ImageAdd[ColorNegate@MorphologicalBinarize[i, $MachineEpsilon], i]`

Comment: @chris Try ImageCompose

Comment: @belisarius: Just doing `ImageCompose` is not enough, as the ellipses don't align.

Comment: @belisarius indeed image compose produces something like this ![ImageCompose Result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HzZhd.png); on top of this I would rather keep a vector description for the grid.

Comment: I must say, I'm amazed at the number of upvotes I've received simply for using a built-in function for its intended purpose! :)

Comment: Rahul, there are lots of functions that people either don't know about, don't know how to use, or have forgotten.  Showing a simple, powerful example is often rewarded with votes around here, especially when the result is a pretty picture.  Don't undervalue your contribution.

Comment: Is there also a way to have Mollweide transformed to Eqirectangular?

Comment: @Hump, sure; look up `ImageForwardTransformation[]`.

Answer (score 35):

To summarize various contributions from this post and [others](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13396) (Rahul Narain, halirutan, cormullion, Szabolcs, belisarius, J.M.) into a single plot, see the following definitions

```
invmollweide[{x_, y_}] := With[{theta = ArcSin[y]},
                           {Pi (x)/(2 Cos[theta]), ArcSin[(2 theta + Sin[2 theta])/Pi]}];
fc[phi_] := Block[{theta},
   If[Abs[phi] == Pi/2, phi,
      theta /. FindRoot[2 theta + Sin[2 theta] == Pi Sin[phi], {theta, phi}]]];
cart[{lambda_, phi_}] := With[{theta = fc[phi]}, {2 /Pi*lambda Cos[theta], Sin[theta]}]
colorbar[{min_, max_}, colorFunction_: Automatic, divs_: 15] :=
   DensityPlot[y, {x, 0, 0.1}, {y, min, max}, AspectRatio -> 15, PlotRangePadding -> 0,
               ColorFunction -> colorFunction, PlotPoints -> {2, divs}, MaxRecursion -> 0,
               FrameTicks -> {None, Automatic, None, None}];

grid0 = With[{delta = Pi/36},
             Table[{lambda, phi}, {phi, -Pi/2, Pi/2, delta}, {lambda, -Pi, Pi, delta}]];
gr1 = Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[0.1], Line /@ grid0, Line /@ Transpose[grid0]},
               AspectRatio -> 1/2];
gr0 = Flatten[{gr1[[1, 2]][[Range[9]*4 - 1]],gr1[[1, 3]][[Range[18]*4 - 3]]}] //
      Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[0.4], #}] &;
grid = Show[{gr1, gr0}, Axes -> False];
grid = grid /. Line[pts_] :> {White, Line[(cart /@ pts)]};
gr2 = StreamPlot[{-1 - Sin[x]^2 + Sin[3y] + Cos[y]^2, 1 + Sin[2x] - Cos[y]^2},
                 {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, AspectRatio -> 1/2, Frame -> False,
                 StreamColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors", StreamPoints -> 250];
gr2 = gr2 /. Arrow[pts_] :> Arrow[(cart /@ pts)] /.
             Point[pts_] :> Point[cart[ pts]] //
             Show[#, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-1, 1}}] &;
img = With[{img=Import["http://i.imgur.com/2ZPBK.jpg"]},
           ImageTransformation[img, invmollweide, {512, 256}*4,
             DataRange -> {{-Pi, Pi}, {-Pi/2, Pi/2}}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-1, 1}},
             Padding -> White]];

Column[{Style["The earth with some crazy vector field", 16],
         Graphics[{Inset[img, {-2, -1}, {0, 0}, {4, 2}], First[grid], First[gr2]},
                  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-1, 1}}, ImageSize -> 800],
         Magnify[Rotate[colorbar[img // ImageData // {Min[#], Max[#]} &, "DarkTerrain"],
                        -90 Degree], 1]}, Center]
```

yields (after a minute or so)

[image: Mathematica graphics]
which illustrates the versatility of Mathematica!

Comment: Nice. Needs a title?

Comment: @cormullion you mean for the plot? As above?

Comment: This would be a nice example for the weekly newsletter. +1

Comment: @chris Yes, anything - just to save me wondering whether it's "The migratory patterns of the Arctic Tern" or something... :)

Comment: At least in 10.0.2 the grid lines look thicker and there are more of them than shown in the answer above.  Was the code changed or has *Mathematica's* rendering changed?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Mathematica's rendering must have changed. I get this with 10.0.1 ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/c0krM.png) I's not THAT different though?

Comment: Now that I look more closely I see that there is a fine grid in yours as well but it is *much* lighter.  I am seeing this:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/usXC4.png

Comment: it is indeed very different. A bit over the top. mine is macos X

Answer (score 15):

Here`s an alternative.

```
 pic = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xyhd.png"]
```

Let's say you are lazy and you don't want to write mathematical equations.

We can use built-in transformations to create domain, image of transformation, and create `InterpolationFunction` based on this data.

```
data = Join @@ Table[{lat, long}, {lat, -89, 89}, {long, -179, 179}];

Clear[x, y];

proj = "Bonne"; (* check GeoProjectionData[]*)


im = First @ GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[data], proj];
g[{x_, y_}] = Interpolation[Transpose[{data, im}]][y, x];

ImageForwardTransformation[
 pic,
 g,
 250 {1, 1},
 DataRange -> {{-1, 1} 180, {-1, 1} 90},  (*expected range may vary with projection ofc*)
 PlotRange -> Pi {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}      (*as above*)
]

(*plot for Bonne, AzimuthalEquidistant,  Albers and WinkelTripel*)
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate lazy, +1.

Comment: Also, less chance of writing the equations wrong.

Comment: @Rahul unfotunately way slower. but fast enough for playing around on small images.

Comment: Is there an inverse of `GeoGridPosition`? `ImageTransformation` is much faster than `ImageForwardTransformation`, I think.

Comment: @Rahul Yes, you have to switch `GeoGridPosition` with `GeoPosition`, more or less. I don;t understand why it is faster, it was natural for me to use forward. It should only care about pixels in result but it slows dramatically when the input is larger.

Comment: @Rahul I will try you suggestion later, I have couple of things to try earlier ;) but feel free to answer youself if you want.

Answer (score 5):

Just to show an even lazier example, you can just use `GeoGraphics` for this.

```
GeoGraphics[GeoRange -> All, 
 GeoBackground -> GeoStyling[{"GeoImage", Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ue2x.png"}], 
 GeoProjection -> "Mollweide"]
```

[image]

Or with the suspiciously familiar object in the other image:

```
GeoGraphics[GeoRange -> All, 
 GeoBackground -> GeoStyling[{"GeoImage", Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xyhd.png"}], 
 GeoProjection -> "Mollweide", Background -> Black]
```

[image]

This works with any projection I've tried in `GeoProjectionData`:

```
GeoGraphics[GeoRange -> All, 
 GeoBackground -> GeoStyling[{"GeoImage", Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xyhd.png"}], 
 GeoProjection -> GeoProjectionData["Bonne"], Background -> Black]
```

[image]

Sadly `GeoProjectionData` doesn't include the [Wasserman Butterfly](https://www.xkcd.com/977/)...

Comment: Thanks for this alternative solution!