# Overlapping accurately Images and Graphics (without loss of resolution)

Tags: graphics, image-processing

**Context**

In a previous [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13361/mollweide-maps-in-mathematica), I learned how to produce these kind of plots, which are of interest in [astrophysics](http://healpix.jpl.nasa.gov) and [geophysics](http://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/GlobalMaps/).

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

I am now interested in combining them.

**Attempt**

For this purpose, @belisarius suggested using the command

```
ImageCompose[mollwide, grid /. Line[a__] :> {White, Line[a]}]
```

which produces this (note the incorrect scaling)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As an other example (to make this question self contained) let us look at `StreamPlot`

```
 gr = StreamPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi/2,
 Pi/2}, AspectRatio -> 1/2, Frame -> False];
 cart[{lambda_, phi_}] :=  With[{theta = fc[phi]}, {2 /Pi*lambda Cos[theta],   Sin[theta]}];
 fc[phi_] := Block[{theta}, If[Abs[phi] == Pi/2, phi,  theta /. 
 FindRoot[2 theta + Sin[2 theta] == Pi Sin[phi], {theta, phi}]]];

 gr2 = gr /. Arrow[pts_] :> Arrow[(cart /@ pts)] /. 
 Point[pts_] :> Point[cart[ pts]] // 
 Show[#, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-1, 1}}] &;

 i = Import["http://tpfto.files.wordpress.com/2012/02/firemap.png"];
 invmollweide[{x_, y_}] := With[{theta = ArcSin[y]}, {Pi (x)/(2 Cos[theta]), 
 ArcSin[(2 theta + Sin[2 theta])/Pi]}];
 moll = ImageTransformation[i, invmollweide, DataRange -> {{-Pi, Pi}, {-Pi/2, Pi/2}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-1, 1}}, Padding -> White];

 ImageCompose[ImageResize[moll, 1200], 
 gr2 /. Arrow[a__] :> {AbsoluteThickness[3], White, Arrow[a]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Question**

1. How can I make sure the image size match?
2. How can I combine them so that the grid remains a vector image rather than a raster?

Comment: Surely `ImageResize[]` can be appropriately applied...

Comment: @J.M. It sort of helps in fact: `ImageCompose[ImageResize[moll, 800], 
 grid /. Line[a__] :> {AbsoluteThickness[2], White, Line[a]}]` produces this [mollweide with grid](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jT9ch.png) which is better in terms of resolution, but the global scaling remains the same.

Comment: Do you use PlotRangePadding -> 0 in your plots? That's usually one way of removing unwanted margins in plots...

Comment: @cormullion Yes! `gr2 = gr /. Arrow[pts_] :> Arrow[(cart /@ pts)] /. 
 Point[pts_] :> Point[cart[ pts]] // 
 Show[#, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-1, 1}},PlotRangePadding -> 0]] &;`  does the trick; please post your answer?

Comment: @chris, will post what I had, for what it's worth

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `Inset` to place the image inside a vector graphics. `Inset` has various parameters to set the size and position of the image places.
To test it you could use a scaled version of an image and overlay it with a grid. You see the lines match exactly:

```
img = ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], {100, 100}];
Graphics[{Inset[img, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {100, 100}], Line[#], 
    Line[Transpose[#]]}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 101}, {-1, 101}}] &@
 Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, 100, 5}, {j, 0, 100, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Earth

Using this in your application, you would only have to copy all the code snips:

```
cart[{lambda_, phi_}] := 
 With[{theta = fc[phi]}, {2/Pi*lambda Cos[theta], Sin[theta]}]
fc[phi_] := 
  Block[{theta}, 
   If[Abs[phi] == Pi/2, phi, 
    theta /. 
     FindRoot[2 theta + Sin[2 theta] == Pi Sin[phi], {theta, phi}]]];

grid = With[{delta = Pi/18/2}, 
   Table[{lambda, phi}, {phi, -Pi/2, Pi/2, delta}, {lambda, -Pi, Pi, 
     delta}]];
gr1 = Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[0.05], Line /@ grid, 
    Line /@ Transpose[grid]}, AspectRatio -> 1/2];
gr0 = Flatten[{gr1[[1, 2]][[Range[9]*4 - 1]], 
     gr1[[1, 3]][[Range[18]*4 - 3]]}] // 
   Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[0.2], #}] &;
gr2 = Table[{Hue[t/Pi], Point[{t, t/2}]}, {t, -Pi, Pi, 1/100}] // 
    Flatten // Graphics;
gr = Show[{gr1, gr0, gr2}, Axes -> True];
earthgrid = 
 gr /. Line[pts_] :> {Orange, Line[cart /@ pts]} /. 
  Point[pts_] :> Point[cart[pts]]
```

Creating an earth-map image

```
invmollweide[{x_, y_}] := 
 With[{theta = ArcSin[y]}, {Pi x/(2 Cos[theta]), 
   ArcSin[(2 theta + Sin[2 theta])/Pi]}];
img =
 With[{i = 
    Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaQGa.jpg"]},
  ImageTransformation[i, invmollweide, {512, 256}, 
   DataRange -> {{-Pi, Pi}, {-Pi/2, Pi/2}}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-1, 1}}, Padding -> White]
  ];
```

And then putting all together

```
Graphics[{Inset[img, {-2, -1}, {0, 0}, {4, 2}], First[earthgrid]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks; isn't your code duplicating the Inset as many times as the size of the table?

Comment: for my purpose it would be `Graphics[{Inset[moll, {-2, -1}, {-2, -1}, {4, 2}], gr2[[1]]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-1, 1}}]`

Comment: @chris (1) no, the `Inset` in my first example is not duplicated. This all is a function and the **result** of the `Table` is going where the `#` are. I added a complete example for your purpose.

Comment: right; I confused /@ with @.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps the `StreamPlot` is being produced with unwanted margins that can be removed using `PlotRangePadding -> 0`? This might be one possible source of the apparent misalignment. Compare the left and right halves of this image: on the left, the original; on the right, with `PlotRangePadding -> 0`.

[image: plot margin illustration]

Comment: +1 I would vote both as good answer if I could!

Comment: halirutan needs the votes more - so near to 10k... :)

Comment: In any case I find this `PlotRangePadding -> 0` option quite useful generically.