# Using transparency in ContourPlot makes mesh visible

Tags: plotting, mac-os-x

I am trying to use a ColorFunction with Opacity in ContourPlot. Here's my code:

```
data = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.75], 10];
d = SmoothKernelDistribution[data];
cf[z_] := {Opacity[z], Red};
sc1 = ContourPlot[
   Evaluate@PDF[d, {x, y}], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50, ColorFunction -> cf, 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> True]
```

And here's what it produces:

[image]

How can the ugly mesh be avoided? I am using Mathematica 8.0.1 in OS X.

Comment: does `Mesh -> None` give what you need? Btw, I don't get the "ugly mesh" with Version 9 on Windows Vista 64 bit.

Comment: @Guillochon Here it works fine Mathematica 9.0.1 Win7 64b

Comment: Mesh -> None is not a legal option for ContourPlot for me. I am using Mathematica 8.0.1 for OS X.

Comment: You may use Mesh->False, but it doesn't  do what you want

Comment: `Method -> {"TransparentPolygonMesh" -> True}`

Comment: @belisarius It is a duplicate, but not of that question.  Check here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1400/12  Mike also gave the solution.  I think this is Mac specific.  @Guillochon -- if you're on OS X, can you tag this question with `osx`?

Comment: Perfectly fine with closing it, but opacity never explicitly appeared in that question, which is when this issue arises.

Comment: @Szabolcs I knew that was out there somewhere. I had the method written down in my "scrapbook" of tips and tricks but not the source.

Comment: As above, what platform are you on? Can you please include that information.

Comment: One observation: none of the solutions so far work when you export the plot to pdf format (although they do work in the notebook - depending on platform as was stated).

Comment: That's OK, running rasterizeBackground (from [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13744/rasterized-image-together-with-vector-graphics-axes/13746#13746)) on the result works well

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using OS X the use undocumented `Method -> {"TransparentPolygonMesh" -> True}`

[image]

Comment: Well, it doesn't solve the problem here

Comment: How do you mean? Am I misreading the question? I thought he wanted the mesh to go (??)

Comment: In my machine the mesh disappears with `Style[sc1, Antialiasing -> False]` but not with this solution. Probably version/platform dependent

Comment: @belisarius Yes, the problem is Mac-specific.

Comment: @Szabolcs I'm on Windows, and I have the same problem. The _solution_ is Mac-specific :)

Comment: @belisarius Did you change your default options to include antialiasing?  I don't see any problem on Windows: [Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Vtpi1.png)

Comment: @Szabolcs The antialiasing option hasn't a "reset to default" here, so it's difficult to know

Comment: @belisarius To be more specific, here on Windows `sc1` looks fine and has anitaliasing.  `Style[sc1, Antialiasing -> True]` has the artefact, and has antialiasing. `Style[sc1, Antialiasing -> False]` doesn't have the artefact and doesn't have antialiasing.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Done

Comment: If you'd like to export antialiased bitmap graphics, but run into this problem, here's a way: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/198/antialiasing-in-3d  And here's what I got: http://i.stack.imgur.com/lkl25.png  Unfortunately the ticks are made very subtle.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are looking at a PDF, I would use [`SmoothDensityHistogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SmoothDensityHistogram.html) to plot it, instead.

```
data = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.75], 10];
d = SmoothKernelDistribution[data];
cf[z_] := {Opacity[z], Red};

sc1 = SmoothDensityHistogram[data , Automatic, "PDF", 
  PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> cf, Mesh -> 10, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5], Black]]
```

[image]

By default, in this case, it was not displaying the contours, so I added them via `Mesh` and `MeshStyle`. Modify to taste.

Comment: I looked at this as an option, but the problem was not being able to get flat shading between the contours.

Comment: @Guillochon, why do you want the flat shading they don't truly represent the function?

Comment: It's a stylistic choice, the smooth coloring is hard to see, and is harder to notice when printed to paper.

Answer (score 3):

Just for behavior documentation. 
Mathematica 8.0 on WinXP.

```
GraphicsRow[Style[sc1, Antialiasing -> #] & /@ {True, False}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: When I tested this on Windows 7, `sc1` *without* any antialiasing option produced an antialiased graphic without a visible mesh.  (I.e. when not specifying Antialiasing at all, the problem didn't appear.)

Comment: I get the same with mma 9.0.0 win7 64 bit http://i.stack.imgur.com/f9um4.png

Comment: @Szabolcs So it's definitely due to a change in defaults. I think specifying the Antialiasing  makes the results portable

Comment: @Ajasja Try including Automatic too in the list of options, not just True and False.  This is what I got with Automatic: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Vtpi1.png

Comment: I have to comment on this again, because it's misleading:  on all Windows systems I tried, there's no problem with the mesh if you don't use any anti-aliasing setting at all.  A fair example would show Antialiasing -> Automatic as well.  This example prevented the original question from being closed as a duplicate even though it really should be.  It's a Mac OS X specific issue which is solved by the suggestion in the accepted answer.

Comment: @Szabolcs This is a cooperatively edited site. Please feel free to update my answer if you feel it's misleading.

Comment: @belisarius I'd have to wait until I get to my office where we have a Windows machine, so it's a bit troublesome ... do you get the mesh with Antialiasing -> Automatic?

Comment: @Szabolcs Nope.

Comment: It seems that there's no issue on Windows then, in the sense that the default settings (`Antialiasing -> Automatic`) do not produce a visible mesh.  On OS X there's still a mesh with `Antialiasing -> False`.  The only solution seems to be `Show[..., Method -> {"TransparentPolygonMesh" -> True}]`.  Do you think we could close this as a duplicate of [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1400/removing-unwanted-appearance-of-underlying-mesh)?  (My close vote is already expired.)

Comment: @Szabolcs Ok. I can't vote bc JM already marked it as dup