# ContourPlot has extra mesh

Tags: plotting, graphics

There is an odd white mesh that appears on top of any contour plot I make.

```
ContourPlot[x + 2 y, {x, 80, 300}, {y, 50, 100}]
```

[image]

Any ideas on how I get rid of this? I've tried a new notebook with just that command but it does not go away.

Just adding that this is also happening in the `ContourPlot` help page so I think some global variable has been set that is doing this. Restarting Mma has not helped.

Version 10.2 on Win 8.1 64-bit.

**Added output of `Options`**

```
Options[ContourPlot]
{AlignmentPoint -> Center, AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> False, 
 AxesLabel -> None, AxesOrigin -> Automatic, AxesStyle -> {}, 
 Background -> None, BaselinePosition -> Automatic, BaseStyle -> {}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None, BoxRatios -> Automatic, ClippingStyle -> None,
  ColorFunction -> Automatic, ColorFunctionScaling -> True, 
 ColorOutput -> Automatic, ContentSelectable -> Automatic, 
 ContourLabels -> Automatic, ContourLines -> True, 
 Contours -> Automatic, ContourShading -> Automatic, 
 ContourStyle -> Automatic, CoordinatesToolOptions -> Automatic, 
 DisplayFunction :> $DisplayFunction, Epilog -> {}, 
 Evaluated -> Automatic, EvaluationMonitor -> None, 
 Exclusions -> Automatic, ExclusionsStyle -> None, 
 FormatType :> TraditionalForm, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> None, 
 FrameStyle -> {}, FrameTicks -> Automatic, FrameTicksStyle -> {}, 
 GridLines -> None, GridLinesStyle -> {}, ImageMargins -> 0., 
 ImagePadding -> All, ImageSize -> Automatic, 
 ImageSizeRaw -> Automatic, LabelStyle -> {}, LightingAngle -> None, 
 MaxRecursion -> Automatic, Mesh -> None, MeshFunctions -> {}, 
 MeshStyle -> Automatic, Method -> Automatic, 
 PerformanceGoal :> $PerformanceGoal, PlotLabel -> None, 
 PlotLegends -> None, PlotPoints -> Automatic, 
 PlotRange -> {Full, Full, Automatic}, PlotRangeClipping -> True, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Automatic, PlotRegion -> Automatic, 
 PlotTheme :> $PlotTheme, PreserveImageOptions -> Automatic, 
 Prolog -> {}, RegionFunction -> (True &), RotateLabel -> True, 
 TargetUnits -> Automatic, Ticks -> Automatic, TicksStyle -> {}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision}
```

Comment: Looks like a `"TransparentPolygonMesh"` mesh problem, but I cannot reproduce it.  Possible duplicate(?): http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1400/removing-unwanted-appearance-of-underlying-mesh

Comment: @MichaelE2 My `Options[ContourPlot]` does not have a `"TransparentPolygonMesh"` in it.  I'll add the output to the questions.

Comment: The usage for the option is through `Method`: `Method -> {"TransparentPolygonMesh" -> True}`  or `False`.  It won't show up in `Options[]`.  Here is an example of its use in `ContourPlot`: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20445/

Comment: @MichaelE2 I saw a post showing that it could be due to `Antialiasing` settings as well. In the end I just did a clean start with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> to wipe whatever was mucking with it in the background. I have to rest some preferences but that is better then having to include an undocumented option in every `ContourPlot` I need.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with version 10.2 on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: There is no white mesh with the above Option[ContourPlot]; Windows 10 and Mma 10.2

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem either (MMA 10.2 on Win7-64). @Edmund what version are you using?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem could not be reproduced.

Comment: Although I unfortunately (or fortunately) can't reproduce it either, maybe you can work around your problem by using [one of the aswers here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3190/245)

Comment: @MarcoB Please give a larger benefit of the doubt on reproducibility.  In this case for example I can easily reproduce the problem.  Not everyone has the same platform and system configuration and many localized idiosyncrasies appear as a result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Closely related:

- [Antialiasing option behaves weird (polygon edges visible in ContourPlot)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/381/121)

I can easily reproduce your problem in 10.1 under Windows 7 merely by setting:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, Antialiasing -> True]
```

Example of output then produced:

[image: mwe of SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, Antialiasing -> True]]

This is a case of anti-aliasing gone wrong, and it is normally handled correctly by the default setting of `Automatic`:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, Antialiasing -> Automatic]
```

If this fixes your problem change [`$FrontEndSession`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/%5C$FrontEndSession.html) to [`$FrontEnd`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/%5C$FrontEnd.html) to make the setting persist.

If setting `Automatic` does *not* fix the problem the cause it very likely the same anyway but from a different source.  Do you have a video card set to *force* AA in all applications?  Try changing that to "application preference" or similar.

Comment: So it seems my question is a duplicate as I didn't know exactly what to search for.

Comment: @Edmund That's OK, and thanks for searching before posting.  Your question will probably help make searching easier for others with the same issue.  Did `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, Antialiasing -> Automatic]` fix the problem?

Comment: Yes, I had upgrading both my graphics drivers. I think it was from the Intel driver as I have upgraded the Nvidia ones many times before without issue.  Also, the default is the Intel on board GPU so Mma was running on that.