# quality when saving as PDF

Tags: graphics, export, pdf-format

```
ComplexRegionPlot[ { Abs[z - 2 - 2 I] <= 2, 0 <= Arg[z] <= Pi/4, Re[z] <= 3, Abs[z - 2 - 2 I] <= 2 && 0 <= Arg[z] <= Pi/4 && Re[z] <= 3 }, {z, 0, 5 + 5 I}, GridLines -> {{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Still want to save as a vector graphics in PDF.
But how would I get ride of the "grid in space"?
i.e. get a filled version, as shown in MMA?

Comment: @Domen Yes, almost identical.......I am also working with "12.3.1" on win10.

Comment: @Domen Then ``Antialiasing -> False`` does not really work in my case though...

Comment: You should really look at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3190/saner-alternative-to-contourplot-fill/3279#3279.  In particular try:  `Export["testCPR-Mesh.pdf", MapAt[cleanRegionPlot, cpr, 1], "PDF"]` (the `MapAt` is because you have a legend).

Answer (score 1):

One way to avoid that is to specify the `PlotStyle`  like this

```
ComplexRegionPlot[{Abs[z - 2 - 2 I] <= 2, 0 <= Arg[z] <= Pi/4, 
  Re[z] <= 3, 
  Abs[z - 2 - 2 I] <= 2 && 0 <= Arg[z] <= Pi/4 && Re[z] <= 3}, {z, 0, 
  5 + 5 I}, GridLines -> {{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions", AspectRatio -> 1, Mesh -> False, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Orange, Green, Red}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.01]]]
```

this is the pdf output

[image]