# How to export a meshless SVG?

Tags: export, svg-format

## This problem does not exist in 13.2.1 anymore

---

I often need to export some svg with mma, but RegionPlot's diagrams will have some extra mesh after exporting SVG:

```
p = RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}];
Export["p.svg", p]
```

[image]

Not only does this make SVG very ugly, but it can lead to very large files. And is this a bug of MMA?

Comment: `p = RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   PlotStyle -> Cyan];
Export["p.svg", p]`

Comment: @cvgmt As the file size is large than before, I think the color just covers those mesh, which actually exists.

Comment: Also look at [257039](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/257039/problem-with-exporting-regionplot-as-pdf).

Comment: Yep, fixed in 13.2.1. Well, there are still some invisible lines...

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников Invisible ?

Comment: Mostly. See SVG in Chrome.

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников I did, but I don't have the invisible line you're talking about. Can you take a picture?

Comment: Here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODDLP.png that is Chrome, but it is more pronounced in Firefox and in pdf in Acrobat.

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников Oh, I noticed it

Comment: That is how this thing looks in Acrobat, when you press edit pdf: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvzmX.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkLBF.png and yes, you can delete it in full: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUjAq.png

Answer (score 6):

```
p = RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   PlotStyle -> {EdgeForm[]}];
Export["p.svg", p]
```

[image]

```
pp= RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   PlotStyle -> {EdgeForm[], FaceForm[Green]}, 
   BoundaryStyle -> None];
Export["pp.svg", pp]
```

[image]

```
ppp = RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   PlotStyle -> {EdgeForm[], FaceForm[None]}, BoundaryStyle -> Red];
Export["ppp.svg", ppp]
```

[image]

Comment: I thought the filesize would be smaller without the grid, but it still looks the same. And As far as I know, MMA doesn't have a parameter for resizing SVG filesize?

Comment: They are smaller in the last case for ppp.svg, for pdf and for svg, cause in acrobat white is just white of the background.

Answer (score 3):

This code almost solves my problem, which will export very **small** and **meshless** SVG file, but the background is not transparent. I don't know how to export an SVG file with the transparent background..

```
p = RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}];
BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[p, Frame -> True];
Export["p.svg", %,Background -> None]
```

Comment: Why not use `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
 ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}}], 
 Frame -> True]` ?

Comment: @cvgmt But the background is [white still](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0FYt.png)

Comment: Open your svg file in gimp and it shows a hatched background suggesting that it is transparent ?

Comment: @Syed No, it is WHITE but not transparent, the transparent background is my after...