# Dealing with RegionPlot artifacts when enabling antialiasing

Tags: plotting, bugs, rendering, antialiasing

**Bug persisting in 13.1.0** [CASE:4953032]

---

For antialiased export, I'm using the following pattern:

```
Rasterize[Style[plot, Antialiasing -> True], ImageSize -> 800,
  RasterSize -> 1600]
```

However, this introduces "polygon" artifacts in my `RegionPlot` plots, any tips for a way around it?

[image]

```
nf[x_] := NumberForm[x, {3, 3}];
rotateVec[angle_, vec_] := N[RotationMatrix[angle] . vec];
simpleNorm[{{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}}] := 
  Max[Sqrt[
   a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 - 
    Sqrt[-4 (b c - a d)^2 + (a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2)^2]]/Sqrt[2], Sqrt[
   a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + 
    Sqrt[-4 (b c - a d)^2 + (a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2)^2]]/Sqrt[2]];
xvec1 = {1, 0};
getBatch[theta_] := {1/2 xvec1, rotateVec[theta, xvec1]};

standardColors = ColorData[97, "ColorList"];

d = 2;
ii = IdentityMatrix[d];
bound = 2.;


setTheta[t0_] := (
   theta = t0;
   H = With[{X = getBatch[theta]}, X . X\[Transpose]];
   Ta[alpha_] := ii - 2 alpha H + alpha^2 H . H;
   obj[alpha_] := simpleNorm@Ta@alpha;
   sol = NMinimize[obj[alpha], alpha];
   point = {alpha /. Last[sol], First@sol};
   curvePlot = 
    Plot[Norm@Ta@alpha, {alpha, alphaStart, alphaEnd}, 
     Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[point]}, 
     AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}];
   tracePlot = 
    Plot[Tr@Ta@alpha, {alpha, alphaStart, alphaEnd}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Directive[Dashed, standardColors[[2]]]}];
   arrowsPlot = Graphics[Arrow[{{0, 0}, #}] & /@ getBatch[theta]];
   );

genPlot[alpha_] := Module[{},
   alphaStart = 0;
   alphaEnd = 3.;
   
   mat0 = Ta[alpha];
   R = Norm[mat0];
   curvePositionPlot = 
    ListPlot[{{alpha, Norm@mat0}}, Filling -> Axis, 
     PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large], FillingStyle -> Dashed];
   curvePositionPlot2 = 
    ListPlot[{{alpha, Tr@mat0}}, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large], 
     FillingStyle -> Dashed];
   boundsPlot0 = 
    ContourPlot[{{x1, x2} . ii . {x1, x2} == 
       R, {x1, x2} . ii . {x1, x2} == Tr@mat0}, {x1, -bound, 
      bound}, {x2, -bound, bound}, Frame -> False, 
     ContourStyle -> {standardColors[[1]], 
       Directive[standardColors[[2]], Dashed]}];
   boundsPlot1 = 
    RegionPlot[{x1, x2} . PseudoInverse[mat0] . {x1, x2} <= 
      1, {x1, -bound, bound}, {x2, -bound, bound}, 
     PlotStyle -> standardColors[[3]]];
   
   boundsPlot = Show[boundsPlot0, boundsPlot1, arrowsPlot];
   curvePlot0 = 
    Show[curvePlot, curvePositionPlot, tracePlot, curvePositionPlot2, 
     PlotLabel -> StringForm["trace=`` norm=``", nf@Tr@mat0, nf@R]];
   GraphicsRow[{boundsPlot, curvePlot0}, 0, Spacings -> 0]
   ];
linePlot = 
  ContourPlot[{x1, x2} . CholeskyDecomposition[H] == 0, {x1, -bound, 
    bound}, {x2, -bound, bound}, 
   ContourStyle -> Directive[Orange, Dashed], 
   PlotLabel -> StringForm["step=``", k]];
setTheta[Pi/4];
Rasterize[Style[genPlot[0.5], Antialiasing -> True], ImageSize -> 800,
  RasterSize -> 1600]
```

Comment: I had filed this on Jul 13. A day later they confirmed this as a bug, case number 4953032. "The cause here is slightly overlapping multi-polygons with transparency in them. The effective opaque fill color of the default PlotStyle when overlaid on a white background. Our developers are investigating the issue, and we will notify you when the issue is fixed".

Comment: @MarcoB just tried the solutions in that post and it didn't work -- the lines reappear when calling Rasterize with antialiasing

Comment: Maybe something like this could work? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/257042/4346

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply `Antialiasing -> False` to `Polygon`s:

```
Rasterize[Style[genPlot[0.5] /. p_Polygon :> Style[p, Antialiasing -> False], 
  Antialiasing -> True], ImageSize -> 800, RasterSize -> 1600]
```

> [image: output]

Comment: upon closer examination of image quality side-by-side, it seems like default Export["anim.gif",frames] already does something like this, lines seem antialiased, and no polygon artifacts