# How to remove meshing while exporting a plot using RegionPlot?

Tags: plotting, export, regions, mesh, pdf-format

I want to plot a region using RegionPlot. The plot looks perfect when it is in mathematica. But when I export the image as .eps or .pdf file a meshgrid is appearing in the final .eps or .pdf file. Here I am attaching the code and final output. Please help me to remove the meshgrid.

```
Im1 = RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 <= 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Mesh -> None, MeshStyle -> None, 
  Frame -> False, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, Method -> {"TransparentPolygonMesh" -> True}]
Export["im2.pdf", Im1, "PDf"]
```

[image]

Comment: or [Problem with exporting RegionPlot as PDF](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/257039/problem-with-exporting-regionplot-as-pdf)

Comment: This has some other problem. e.g. `ff = Region[
  Style[ImplicitRegion[2.5 <= y <= 2.67, {{x, 7, 14}, {y, 0, 3}}], 
   RGBColor[0.1, 0.6, 0.3], Opacity[0.6]], PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]` Doing this,  you will find that, somehow the corners of the plot chopped off.

Comment: MMA version 13.2 Windows 10. There is no mesh in the PDF file.