# Remove mesh triangles in contour plot

Tags: plotting

How do I get rid of the mesh in this contour plot?

```
 ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
    Contours -> {1.0, 4.0, 10.5}, ContourStyle -> None, 
    ContourShading -> {RGBColor[1, .2, 0, .1], RGBColor[1, .2, 0, .3], 
    RGBColor[1, .2, 0, .5], RGBColor[1, .2, 0, .7]}]
```

[image]

Setting the option `Mesh->None` doesn't help.  I'm using Mathematica 12.1.1

Comment: That's odd I don't see this in 12.1.1 Windows 10. Try adding `MeshStyle -> None` or `BaseStyle->{EdgeForm[None]}` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Still problematic with those options set.  I'm on MacOS 10.13.6

Comment: Duplicates: [(1400)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1400), [(20445)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20445)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Removing unwanted appearance of underlying mesh](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1400/removing-unwanted-appearance-of-underlying-mesh/1402#1402), which is a duplicate:

```
ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
 Contours -> {1.0, 4.0, 10.5}, ContourStyle -> None, 
 ContourShading -> {RGBColor[1, .2, 0, .1], RGBColor[1, .2, 0, .3], 
   RGBColor[1, .2, 0, .5], RGBColor[1, .2, 0, .7]}, 
 Method -> {"TransparentPolygonMesh" -> True}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The mesh comes from reducing the opacity. To avoid the mesh, use fully opaque colors.

```
$Version

(* "12.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10},
 Contours -> {1.0, 4.0, 10.5},
 ContourStyle -> None,
 ContourShading ->
  {LightRed, Pink, Red, Darker[Red]}]
```

[image]