# fail to export to eps or pdf in vector form in 11.0 version

Tags: export, pdf-format, eps-format

I meet a problem that the figure exported to eps or pdf is never in vector form, i.e., I can not select anything on the figure as if it is a jpg. below is an example:

```
wsFrame =  RegionPlot3D[0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1.2},   LabelStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 15, FontFamily -> "Times"],   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 10,   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[0.6 z, 0.8, 1, 0.4]],   Boxed -> False, AxesLabel -> None, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},   Ticks -> {{-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1}, {-1, -0.5, 0.5, 1}, {-1, -0.5, 0.5,      1}}, AspectRatio -> 1, Mesh -> 14, ImageSize -> Medium,   ViewPoint -> {1.7, 1.7, 1.2}]; Export[FileNameJoin@{NotebookDirectory[], "1" <> ".pdf"}, wsFrame]
```

Above is a very simple plot, so I don't know why it does not work. I do find a way to cope with this:

```
Export[FileNameJoin@{NotebookDirectory[], "LMPwsFrame" <> ".pdf"},  Graphics[Inset[wsFrame], ImageSize \[RightArrow] 16 cm]]
```

but very often I need to deal with more complex figures, which, if I export like this, will yield a figure of about 30Mb or even 100Mb, which is very difficult to open or use in other software.

So I wonder how can I export those figures correctly? Notice that I mostly want the labels and frames to be vector form, the plot itself does not necessarily be in vector form. Thanks.

Comment: The topic of vector export of 3D figures has been discussed at some length on this site; try a search: [Export to vector form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=export+to+vector+form).

Comment: Strongly related: "[Mathematica: Rasters in 3D graphics](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6301676/590388)."

Comment: Related: "[Rasterized image together with vector-graphics axes](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13744/280)."

Comment: Strongly related: "[Exporting graphics to PDF - huge file](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1542/280)."