# Raster ListDensityPlot with vector axes and labels

Tags: plotting, export, rasterize

Is there an easy way to export a raster DensityPlot or ListDensityPlot but with vector axes, lines and label? I didn't find an easy answer in other questions.

Comment: See [Rasterized density plot with vector axes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71870/27951) and [Saner alternative to ContourPlot fill](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3196/27951) and the questions linked there.

Comment: Thank you, Marco. But they don't seem to answer to the question. Is it possible that there is not an easy and compact solution?

Comment: [`rasterizeBackground`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13746/22013)?

Comment: Ok, thank you. It works if PlotLegends is not specified in the original Plot. Do you have an idea how to modify rasterizeBackground ?

Comment: In the end I solved it by plotting the original image without PlotLegends, then by using Legended:

imgLegended=Legended[rasterizeBackground[img], Placed[BarLedend[...],position]]

and exporting it with
Export["filename.pdf",imgLegended]

Comment: @jset See my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153557/36508) for an improved version of `rasterizeBackground`, especially the version in the "Update" section. That one can handle legends plots and similar structures without issues