# Export to PDF: DensityPlot & AllowRasterization->False

Tags: graphics, export, interpolation, image, pdf-format

How to get *production*-quality vector graphic exported from Mathematica that looks like what is plotted in Mathematica. Example code:

```
plt = DensityPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}];
Export["C:\\test.pdf", plt, "AllowRasterization" -> False (*This is important*)];
```

What image plt looks like in Mathematica:
[image: What image plt looks like in Mathematica]

What pdf export of plt looks like
[image]

which no longer has the color interpolation, but is tessellated. I've looked around a bit, and can't seem to find an answer. Any solutions?

Ps.  Setting "AllowRasterization" -> True  makes the file 9 MB, since It renders all the little tets; otherwise, the file is 0.1 MB in pure vector form.

Comment: [`rasterizeBackground`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13746/22013) might be helpful.

Comment: Hm. I use Mathematica version 11.0.1 on macos 10.13.3 and to my own supprise, it seems to work with `Export["test.pdf", plt];`. Indeed, Mathematica does _not_ rasterize on export, but it also cannot reimport the result. The resulting PDF is about 533 KB large and renders a bit slow and buggy in Preview.  `"AllowRasterization" -> True` leads ot a 66 KB pdf. Note also that the image you posted does not coincide with `plt`.

Comment: You could use the function `contourDensityPlot` described in my answer to [Saner alternative to ContourPlot fill](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3196/245). This is probably a duplicate of that question.