# Plotting a 4dimensional spherical function In mathematica

Tags: plotting

Im trying to plot the results of the schroedinger equation for hydrogen in mathematica

this is the function I defined:

```
  Wavefunction[r_, w_, a_, n_, l_, m_] := 
 LaguerreL[n - l - 1, 2*l + 1, 2*r/n]*LegendreP[l, m, Cos[w]]*
  E^(I*m*a)*Sqrt[((2*l + 1)*(l - m)!)/(4*Pi *(l + m)!)]*
  E^-(r/(n))*(2*r/(n))^l*
  Sqrt[(2/(n))^3*(n - l - 1)!/(4*Pi*(n + l)!)]
```

Its a bit messy and not necessarily fault free yet, but It doesnt really change my question much. What would be a smart way of plotting this function. its in spherical coordinates, n l and m are quantum numbers, r the radius w and a are angles, LaguerreL and LegendreP are built in functions.

I looked at contourplots and density plots, But I cant come up with a statisfying result in spherical coordinates (and way to display the resulting wavefunctions with say cutouts or translucency)

ps: this is basically what I hope to plot. the electron orbitals of hydrogen:
[hydrogen orbitals](http://th02.deviantart.net/fs71/PRE/f/2012/259/3/d/hydrogen_orbitals___poster_by_darksilverflame-d5ev4l6.png)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: The choice is very much a matter of taste.

Comment: related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19575/1089 or http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25078/1089 and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25516/1089

Comment: I looked at thatone, but I couldnt get the nuts and bolts too match, mainly due to this being in spherical coordinates