# How can I reliably plot ellipse-field streamlines?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, vector

I am trying to replicate some standard structures in the study of ellipse fields in Mathematica, and I'm having much more trouble than is really reasonable, so I'd like to put this on the floor here in the hope that someone here can point out some simpler method that I'm currently not seeing.

More specifically, I would like to have simple and reliable ways to produce streamline plots like the following,

> [image]

from the paper

> Geometry of phase and polarization singularities, illustrated by edge
>   diffraction and the tides. M.V. Berry. M.S. Soskin, M.V. Vasnetsov (Eds.), [Second International Conference on Singular Optics, Proc. SPIE, 4403, p. 1 (2001)](https://doi.org/10.1117/12.428252). [Author eprint](https://michaelberryphysics.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/berry330.pdf).

Basically, the deal is the following: you have some complex-valued vector field, say,
$$
\mathbf F(x,y) = (1+iby, i(1-x))
$$
(where $b$ is a parameter, the main interesting points of which are $b\in\{-1,1,3\}$), and you see it as encoding an ellipse at each point much in the same way as for an electromagnetic wave (i.e. the ellipse is traced out by $\mathrm{Re}(\mathbf F(x,y)e^{-it})$ for $t\in[0,2\pi]$); you then look for the streamlines of the major and minor axis of these ellipses.

The major and minor axis of each ellipse can be obtained as in [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/308009/how-can-i-get-the-axes-of-the-polarization-ellipse-from-the-jones-vector-of-the) as the real and imaginary parts of
$$
\mathbf A+i\mathbf B = \frac{\sqrt{\mathbf E^*\cdot \mathbf E^*}}{\left|\sqrt{\mathbf E^*\cdot \mathbf E^*}\right|}\mathbf E,
$$
and as a naive start, one can do fairly well by putting these in explicitly and asking for a StreamPlot:

```
Block[{F, A, B, R = 0.6},
 F[x_, y_] = {1 + I b y, I (1 - x)};
 A[x_, y_] = 
  1/Abs[Sqrt[F[x, y]\[Conjugate].F[x, y]\[Conjugate]]] Re[
    Sqrt[F[x, y]\[Conjugate].F[x, y]\[Conjugate]] F[x, y]];
 B[x_, y_] = 
  1/Abs[Sqrt[F[x, y]\[Conjugate].F[x, y]\[Conjugate]]] Im[
    Sqrt[F[x, y]\[Conjugate].F[x, y]\[Conjugate]] F[x, y]];
 Table[
  StreamPlot[
   A[x, y]
   , {x, -R, R}, {y, -R, R}
   , ImageSize -> 400
   ]
  , {b, {-1, 1, 5}}]
 ]
```

[image]

However, I have a couple of problems here:

- I cannot control where the streamlines start and stop, and the defaults do some pretty ugly spacing and they start and eliminate streamlines in mid-flight, which I would like to avoid. For some reason, if I try to give it an explicit [`StreamPoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StreamPoints.html) specification, Mathematica just hangs forever.
- The stream plots have a discontinuity on the negative $x$ axis, where the major axis $\mathbf A(x,y)$ discontinuously changes sign. This discontinuity is both:

  - spurious, because ellipses are symmetric and it doesn't matter which way you choose the axis, but also
  - unavoidable, because of the way these ellipse points have been set up: if you track the ellipse around the origin, it will come back to itself while acquiring a 180° rotation; this won't affect the ellipse but it means that $\mathbf A(x,y)$ must change direction at some point.

I would like to have a solid construction that allows me to get past both of these limitations, but after several attacks I can't really get there. I'm OK with `NDSolve`ing my way through this, but it keeps choking on the discontinuity and with the accumulation point at the origin.

(Also, I am wary of solutions that place explicit stock in the symmetry of the problem, by e.g. splitting up the plane into different regions. It's not a deal killer, but I would like to be able to handle cases where the branch cut falls along some non-symmetrically-placed line.)

Does anyone see how this can be done?

Comment: For a different way of visualizing general polarization states, see also [Visualizing vector spherical harmonics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25078/245) - that's not an answer to your question, unfortunately.

Answer (score 13):

## Use NDSolve to solve for y(x)

Perhaps this serves as a starting point. Shown below is the case when `b = -1`.

Each streamline is obtained from `NDSolve`. Initial conditions in the form of $y(x_n) = y_n$ are chosen with a simple lattice, `points` (shown as red dots).

Not all systems can be solved, at least when $y(x_n < 0) = 0$, so the outputs from `NDSolve` that are not results of successful solution are filtered out by `Cases`. But then not all `InterpolatingFunction` are valid either; those that aren't have equal domain endpoints. They are filtered out by `Select`.

```
Clear[r, b, f, ff, x, y, z, vectorfield, points, plots, sols];

r = 6/10;
b = -1;
f[x_, y_] := {1 + I b y, I (1 - x)};
ff[x_, y_] := Sqrt[Conjugate[f[x, y]] . Conjugate[f[x, y]]];
z[x_, y_] := f[x, y] ff[x, y] / Abs[ff[x, y]];

vectorfield = Re @ z[x, y[x]];
points = Tuples[Subdivide[-r, r, 5], 2];

sols = NDSolveValue[
  {y'[x] == Divide @@ Reverse @ vectorfield, y[First @ #] == Last @ #},
  y,
  {x, -r, r}
] & /@ points;

plots = Composition[
  Select[#, Unequal @@ First[#["Domain"]] &] &,
  Cases[#, _InterpolatingFunction] &
] @ sols;

Show[
  {
    ListPlot[points, PlotStyle -> Red],
    Plot[#[x], Evaluate @ {x, Sequence @@ First[#["Domain"]]}] & /@ plots
  },
  Axes -> False,
  Frame -> True,
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  PlotRange -> {{-r, r}, {-r, r}},
  PlotRangePadding -> None
]
```

[image: Streamlines]

The problem really is how to construct `points` such that you have beautifully spaced streamlines.

## Specify Better Sample Points

Since this is an aesthetic issue, human intervention is going to be necessary, on a case-by-case basis.

For example, with

```
points = Composition[
  Map[First],
  Cases[#, _Point] &,
  RegionIntersection /@ # &,
  Subsets[#, {2}] &
] @ {
  InfiniteLine[{{-r, 0}, {r, r}}],
  InfiniteLine[{{-r, 0}, {r, -r}}],
  Sequence @@ Table[InfiniteLine[{{n, -r}, {n, r}}], {n, -r, r, 1/10}]
}
```

we can obtain this:

[image: Streamlines]

---

Now I can produce other plots too. When `b = 3` (monstar):

[image: Streamlines]

When `b = 1` (lemon):

[image: Streamlines]

## Downsides

Note though that the approach finds $y(t)$ through $y(x(t))$, which is a workaround for not knowing the bounds of $t$ within the domain and range of interest. One downside is that if a particular streamline isn't a function $y(x)$ in a domain of interest, `NDSolve` only goes as far as it is a function and stops. For example, with

```
vectorfield = {-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2} /. y -> y[x]
points = {{-2, 1/2}}
```

we get this:

[image: Streamline]

In such cases, we have to pick up from the terminal point somehow, in order to continue the streamline towards its accumulation point or the frame edge.

For example, after obtaining `plots[[1]]` above, we could slightly shift the terminal point (in an appropriate direction), feed it back to `points`:

```
terminus = Last @ Last @ plots[[1]]["Domain"]
points = Append[{terminus, plots[[1]][terminus] + 1/1000}] @ points
```

and solve again to obtain

[image: Streamline]

It's easy to specify `points` that build continuous streamlines for the OP's problem. This is not easy in general.

Another related downside of the approach is that it doesn't work if some parts of the streamlines within the frame of interest is parallel to the y-axis.

## Solve for x(t) and y(t) instead

To address both downsides, we could switch to the conventional way, i.e. solving for $y(t)$ and $x(t)$. We may designate $t = 0$ to be where our sample points are. But because we don't know the appropriate bounds of $t$ to specify for `NDSolve`, we may try some small range at first, e.g. $t \in [-1/10, 1/10]$.

```
vectorfield = Re @ z[x[t], y[t]];
points = Composition[
  Map[First],
  Cases[#, _Point] &,
  RegionIntersection /@ # &,
  Subsets[#, {2}] &
] @ {
  InfiniteLine[{{-r, 0}, {r, r}}],
  InfiniteLine[{{-r, 0}, {r, -r}}],
  Sequence @@ Table[InfiniteLine[{{n, -r}, {n, r}}], {n, -r, r, 1/10}]
};
sols = NDSolveValue[
  {
    x'[t] == First @ vectorfield,
    y'[t] == Last @ vectorfield,
    x[0] == First @ #,
    y[0] == Last @ #
  },
  {x, y},
  {t, -1/10, 1/10}
] & /@ points;
plots = Cases[sols, {_InterpolatingFunction, _InterpolatingFunction}];
Show[
  {
    ListPlot[points, PlotStyle -> Red],
    ParametricPlot[
      {#[[1]][t], #[[2]][t]},
      Evaluate @ {t, Sequence @@ First[#[[1]]["Domain"]]}
    ] & /@ plots
  },
  Axes -> False,
  Frame -> True,
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  PlotRange -> {{-r, r}, {-r, r}},
  PlotRangePadding -> None
]
```

from which we obtain

[image: Streamlines]

which tells us that perhaps $t \in [-1, 1]$ (i.e. putting `{t, -1, 1}` in `NDSolve`) should suffice to fill up the frame. And indeed, it leads to [the previous plot above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDaa8.png).

To illustrate that the downsides have been eliminated, consider a wholly vertical vector field

```
vectorfield = {0, 1}
points = Table[{n, 0}, {n, -r, r}]
```

from which we obtain

[image: Vertical streamlines]

The approach should be robust enough for most well-behaved vector fields now. For example,

```
r = 3;
vf = {y, -y + x - x^3};
vectorfield = vf /. {x -> x[t], y -> y[t]};
points = Composition[
  Fold[If[EuclideanDistance[Last[#1], #2] < 1, #1, Append[#1, #2]] &],
  Level[#, {-2}] &,
  MeshPrimitives[#, 0] &,
  DiscretizeRegion,
  ImplicitRegion[Norm[#] == 3, {x, y}] &
] @ vf;
sols = NDSolveValue[
  {
    x'[t] == First @ vectorfield,
    y'[t] == Last @ vectorfield,
    x[0] == First @ #,
    y[0] == Last @ #
  },
  {x, y},
  {t, -10, 10}
] & /@ points;
plots = Cases[sols, {_InterpolatingFunction, _InterpolatingFunction}];
Show[
  {
    StreamPlot[vf, {x, -r, r}, {y, -r, r}, StreamStyle -> LightGray],
    ListPlot[points, PlotStyle -> Red],
    ParametricPlot[
      {#[[1]][t], #[[2]][t]},
      Evaluate @ {t, Sequence @@ First[#[[1]]["Domain"]]}
    ] & /@ plots
  },
  Axes -> False,
  Frame -> True,
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  PlotRange -> {{-r, r}, {-r, r}},
  PlotRangePadding -> None
]
```

Note that the sample points have been chosen in a less boring way.

[image: Streamlines of global attractor of damped conservative system]

Comment: Those are some *very* nice plots - your approach looks unorthodox at first glance but if it works it works. I need to take it for a spin to see how robust it is, but it looks great.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Thanks. The answer has been updated to be more orthodox and robust now.