# Using map projections with astronomical data

Tags: plotting, astronomy, projection

I noticed that all important "Geoprojections" are available in projections for a spherical reference models: GeoProjectionData function;

1 - I am trying using the sinusoidal projection for astronomical data purposes.  I want to use the frames of this projection to plot astronomical points in that map , using right ascension and declination as the coordinates, both in degrees.

In the link below, is a data that can be used, the format is { {RA,DEC, Velociy},....}. Just need the RA, DEC parameters.

[DataSample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n542435m9appl9l/DadosRad2014_RADECVELOC_15124_1024.dat?dl=0)

a. I got the data in {Dec, Ra} :

```
p = Reverse[#] & /@ rad[[All, {1, 2}]]
```

b.then I transformed the parameters DEC RA, to sinusoidal numbers:

```
dat = GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[p], "Sinusoidal"][[1]]
```

c. I did the following code:

```
 GeoListPlot[dat, GeoRange -> All, GeoProjection -> "Sinusoidal", 
 GeoGridLines -> Automatic, 
 GeoGridLinesStyle -> Directive[Dashing[{0.0005, 1 - 0.9950}], Green],
  GeoBackground -> Black, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"RA (\[Degree])", "DEC (\[Degree])"},  
 PlotMarkers -> Style[".", 10, Red]]
```

And the resulting plot is:

[image: SINUSOIDAL PROJECTION PLOT]

But no data was plotted.

And the ranges of  Frame Axis are wrong:  the horizontal axis has to be  middle to left 0 90  180, and middle to right 0 (or 360)  270  180.

In the Vertical Axis: -90(bottom) 0(center) +90(top)

EDIT 1:

The link to wolfram math world about sinusoidal projection : [Sinusoidal](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SinusoidalProjection.html)

Comment: [Cross posted on WC](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/427526?p_p_auth=A5dwSVY6)

Comment: Yes, Any problem? Or the fori are the same?

Comment: [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13361/mollweide-maps-in-mathematica) might be of interest?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*Edit*: for general approach to Ticks, go there: [GeoProjection for astronomical data - wrong ticks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89792/5478)

---

```
data = Cases[ Import[FileNames["*.dat"][[1]]],
              {a_, b_, c_} :> {b, Mod[a, 360, -180]}]; (*thanks to bbgodfrey*)
```

To show points you have to stick with `GeoGraphics`. `GeoListPlot` is designed for `Entities`.

To add something more to the question I changed Ra to hours.

```
    GeoGraphics[{Red, Point@GeoPosition@data}, 
      GeoRange -> {All, {-180, 180}},
      PlotRangePadding -> Scaled@.01,
      GeoGridLinesStyle -> Directive[Green, Dashed], 
      GeoProjection -> "Sinusoidal", 
      GeoGridLines -> Automatic, 
      GeoBackground -> Black, 
      Axes -> True, 
      ImagePadding -> 25, ImageSize -> 800, 
      Ticks -> {Table[{N[i Degree], Row[{Mod[i/15 + 24, 24]," h"}]}, {i, -180, 180, 30}], 
                Table[{N[i Degree], Row[{i, " \[Degree]"}]}, {i, -90, 90, 15}]}, 
      Background -> Black, 
      AxesStyle -> White, 
      TicksStyle -> 15]
```

[image]

Or change every option with `Axes` to `Frame` and:

[image]

---

With coloring:

```
pre = Cases[ Import[FileNames["*.dat"][[1]]], {a_, b_, c_} :> {b, Mod[a, 360, -180], c}];
data = pre[[All, {1, 2}]];
col = Blend[{Yellow, Red}, #] & /@ Rescale[pre[[All, 3]]];



GeoGraphics[{AbsolutePointSize@5, 
  Point[GeoPosition@data, VertexColors -> (col)]}, ...
```

[image]

---

```
pics = Table[
   GeoGraphics[{AbsolutePointSize@5, 
     Point[GeoPosition[{#, Mod[#2, 360, -180 + t]} & @@@ data], 
      VertexColors -> (col)]}, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled@.01,
    GeoGridLinesStyle -> Directive[Green, Dashed], 
    GeoProjection -> "Bonne", GeoGridLines -> Automatic, 
    GeoBackground -> Black, ImagePadding -> 55, ImageSize -> 400, 
    GeoRange -> "World", GeoCenter -> GeoPosition[{0, t}],
    Background -> Black, FrameStyle -> White, FrameTicksStyle -> 15],
   {t, -180, 170, 5}];

Export["gif.gif", pics, "DisplayDurations" -> 1/24.]
```

[image]

Comment: I interpret the first bullet under "Details and Options" in the `GeoListPlot` documentation to mean that it accepts information acceptable to `GeoPosition`, which takes numerical locations as well entities.  In any case, nice job!

Comment: @bbgodfrey Good point! and it works: `GeoListPlot[{GeoPosition /@ data},...` but you have to `Map`... which is slower... Don't ask me why one have to map..

Comment: Kuba , amazing..Well, only thing is that the horizontal scale is inverted. The correct would be:  12....4...2 0 20...18....12. Think that you are running as a clock to the left from zero, turn around in the "back" of the map and returning through th right corner. But camon, it almost an masterpiece what both guys have done, :). A last question, I need to use a coloring (function or data) for each point,  is that possible ? Lets say that I have data = {{a,b,c},....} , where c, is parameter that I want do color the points {a,b}, it is the Velocity parameter in the sample.

Comment: @locometro Thanks, I will come back here as soon as I understand (or fail) what's going on [there](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72476/5478).

Comment: @locometro coloring added. unfortunately I don't know how to reverse Ra quickly. But I will try one day, don't have more time now. Good luck.

Comment: Masterpiece.Thanks again

Comment: Marvelous. How to modify it to work with `Mollweide` projection? I mean, it works when `Sinusoidal` is changed to `Mollweide`, but then the (white) ticks do not coincide with (green) lines. I used today for the first time the `Geo...` commands so I have no idea how does it work. I expected than a simple change of projection would make everything fit.

Comment: @corey979 sorry for delay, a lot on my head lately, hope I've answerd all your questions. :)

Answer (score 12):

Import data (from wherever it is located):

```
rad = Import["C:/Temp/DadosRad2014_RADECVELOC_15124_1024.dat"]
```

Reverse first two elements of each sublist of `rad`, assure that RA lies in between -180 and 180, and discard third element;

```
p = Cases[rad, {a_, b_, c_} -> {b, Mod[a, 360, -180]}];
```

Fix `GeoGridLines`, adjust `ImageSize`, and adjust `FrameTicks` and `FrameLabel` to reflect that angles are measure in radians:

```
dat = GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[p], "Sinusoidal"][[1]];
grid = GeoListPlot[dat, GeoRange -> All, GeoProjection -> "Sinusoidal", 
  GeoGridLines -> Automatic, GeoGridLinesStyle -> Directive[Dashing[{.01, .005}], Green], 
  GeoBackground -> Black, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"RA (rad)", "DEC (rad)"}, 
  PlotMarkers -> Style[".", 10, Red], ImageSize -> Large,
  FrameTicks -> {{-Pi, -Pi/2, 0, Pi/2, Pi}, {-Pi/2, 0, Pi/2}}]
```

[image: grid]

Although, for reasons that are unclear, the data points do not appear on the grid, they can be plotted separately.

```
data = ListPlot[dat, PlotStyle -> Red, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"RA (rad)", "DEC (rad)"}, ImageSize -> Large, 
  PlotRange -> {{-Pi, Pi}, {-Pi/2, Pi/2}}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{-Pi, -Pi/2, 0, Pi/2, Pi}, {-Pi/2, 0, Pi/2}}]
```

[image: data]

Although attempting to directly overlay the two plots with `Show` generates errors, it is possible to overlay the `Graphics` `Part` of `grid` with `data` to obtain the desired result.  (The order of the two plots in `Show` matters.)

```
Show[grid[[1]], data, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: grid plus data]

**Update**

It turns out that `GeoListPlot` did not display the data points in the procedure above, because `GeoPosition` is not `Listable`.  This can be overcome by `Thread`ing `Geoposition` over the data points (or `Map`ping it, as suggested by Kuba in a Comment):

```
GeoListPlot[Thread[GeoPosition[p]], GeoRange -> All, GeoProjection -> "Sinusoidal", 
 GeoGridLines -> Automatic, GeoGridLinesStyle -> Directive[Dashing[{.01, .005}], Green], 
 GeoBackground -> Black, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"RA", "DEC"}, 
 PlotMarkers -> Style[".", 20, Red], ImageSize -> Large, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{-Pi + .001, Row[{180, " \[Degree]"}]}, {-N[Pi/2], Row[{90, " \[Degree]"}]},
 {0., Row[{0, " \[Degree]"}]}, {0.5 Pi, Row[{270, " \[Degree]"}]}, 
 {Pi - .001, Row[{180, " \[Degree]"}]}}, {{-0.5 Pi, -Row[{90, " \[Degree]"}]}, 
 {0., Row[{0, " \[Degree]"}]}, {0.5 Pi, Row[{90, " \[Degree]"}]}}}]
```

(The choice of `FrameTicks` is motivated by one of the OP`s Comments.)

[image: threaded result]

Comment: I thought two things, first the RA range runs from 0 to 360, my doubt is if sinusoidal conversion takes this account. As in geographic coordinates it has 0 -> 180, or 0 -> - 180, there is no long above +- 180.

Comment: maybe,but If you see the graphic, just one side is plotted.

Comment: bb, its almost there... SO I think if I could creat my own sinusoidal plot, with frames etc... I know that geographics plot are not ideal for using astronomical data, but while wolfram does not see astronomical area closer, we ll have to improvised...Or do a specific code for astro plotting...

Comment: @locometro Glad I could help.  If the Answer meets your needs, please accept it.  Also, if you do not mind, I may ask a more general Question about whether `GeoListPlot` does not work due to a bug or because we choose the wrong options.  I have learned a lot investigating the guts of `GeoListPlot`, but not enough to know the root cause.

Comment: Inverted in which respect, left to right, top to bottom, something else?  Easy to fix.

Comment: To be clear, you would like tick horizontal labels to be 180, 90, 0, 270, 180 (from left to right)?  Perhaps, vertical labels of -90, 90 (from bottom to top) too?  These can be done but probably not until this evening.  Does the figure itself need changes?  By the way, you might want to delete any old Comments of yours that no longer are relevant.  I just eliminated a few of mine with no archival value.

Comment: yes, the labels are like that, the vertical would be : top 90, center 0, bottom -90 (of  course, the points are not in degrees , but the ticks represents the planisphere scale in degrees, I know the right would be using the same scale of sinusoidal points, but for  a question of clarity the ticks in degrees are more suitable for positioning  in sky understandings)