# GeoGraphics: problem with GeoPosition in shifted projections

Tags: functions, bugs, curated-data, geography, projection

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 11.0.0**

---

#### A remark about the answer:

My work around is only nice for simple cases with points. More general should include proper polygons splitting on antimeridian.

---

I'd expect `GeoGraphics` to handle positions of points since they are provided with `GeoPosition` wrapper.

But it is not the case for every projection:

```
Table[
 GeoGraphics[Point@GeoPosition[{0, 90}], GeoRange -> "World", 
                                         GeoCenter -> GeoPosition[{0, center}], 
                                         BaseStyle -> AbsolutePointSize@12, 
                                         GeoProjection -> i]
 ,
 {center, {-180, 0}},
 {i,      GeoProjectionData[][[;; 5]]}
]
```

[image]

As we can see, when `GeoCenter` is not default `{0,0}`, some points are missing for couple of projections.

One can correct this manually but it is not consistent at all:

```
{##, GeoGraphics[Point@GeoPosition[#2], GeoRange -> "World", 
                                         GeoCenter -> GeoPosition[{0, -180}], 
                                         GeoProjection -> #]} & @@@ {  
{"Equirectangular", {0, 90}}, {"Mollweide", {0, 90}}, {"Mollweide", {0, -270}}} // Grid
```

[image]

---

#### V11.0.0 edit

```
Grid@Transpose@
  Table[GeoGraphics[Point@GeoPosition[{0, 90}], GeoRange -> "World", 
    GeoCenter -> GeoPosition[{0, center}], 
    BaseStyle -> AbsolutePointSize@12, 
    GeoProjection -> i], {center, {-180, 0}}, {i, 
    GeoProjectionData[][[2 ;; 7]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Points would not plot at all in Question [72426](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72426/using-map-projections-with-astronomical-data/72442?noredirect=1#comment198763_72442).  This may be a related issue.  Alternatively, I may have made an error.  Win 8.1 (64 bit)

Comment: @bbgodfrey I think it is slightly related but the main problem there is that one should use `GeoGraphics` not `GeoListPlot`. Take a look at the answer I've added.

Comment: @Kuba I am not that savvy in every field, could you please asks about deeper functionality on Wolfram Community? It is much easier to get a relevant developer to comment there. For example a recent thing that you know: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/427526

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Sure, I just wanted to ask if you are surprised by this behaviour or not. :)

Answer (score 11):

Here's a workaround for 10.x.x versions.

It seems that within the projected area is everything with *longitude* in interval: `{t-180, t+180}` and if you set `t = -180` algorithm does not care that it is plotting `{-360 , 0}` while original data has domain `{-180, 180}`.

We have to take care of `Mod` ourselves:

```
pos = Cases[ CountryData["World", "SchematicCoordinates"], {_, _Real}, \[Infinity]];

Manipulate[
 GeoGraphics[{Red, AbsolutePointSize@7, Point@GeoPosition[{#, Mod[#2, 360, -180 + t]} & @@@ pos]},
    GeoRange -> "World",
    GeoProjection -> "Sinusoidal", 
    Frame -> True, 
    FrameTicks -> {{{-180 Degree, t - 180}, {0 Degree, t}, {180 Degree, t + 180}}, Automatic},
    GeoCenter -> GeoPosition[{0, t}],
    ImageSize -> 800,
    GeoGridLines -> Automatic, 
    GeoGridLinesStyle -> Black, 
    GeoBackground -> White, 
    PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]],
 {t, -180, 180}]
```

[image: animated sinusoidal projection]

Comment: Today I ve learned a lot, Kuba. Can I do the same in my question? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72426/using-map-projections-with-astronomical-data

Comment: @locometro Me too, thanks for asking this question, I had no motivation to play with it till now. I hope WRI will fix those problems and include features for astronomers :) p.s. remember that you can [upvote](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) topics that you find useful.

Comment: This beatiful animation!!!

Comment: @locometro Sure, [added](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/72479/5478)