# Problem drawing a GeoPath polygon with GeoGraphics

Tags: graphics, geography

I want to draw some polygons bounded with various geographic coordinates. For example, here is the code to draw a triangle between New York, Cape Town and Beijing.

```
GeoGraphics[
 FilledCurve[{GeoPath[{{47, -75}, {-34, 18}, {40, 116}}, 
    CurveClosed -> True]}], GeoProjection -> "Mollweide", 
 GeoRange -> "World"]
```

The resulting graphic does not look good:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How can I achieve a correct drawing of polygons with `GeoGraphics`?

edit: For clarification, I don't want polygons with straight lines but [`GeoPath`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoPath.html) projections (Geodesic, Rhumb, Loxodrome, etc).

Comment: @Kuba if I omit the `ClosedCurve` option it just draws a straight line, this is not ok (it doesn't project the line on the map using the selected (in this case, Mollweide) projection).

Comment: The problem is that it is closer to go east from Bejing  and that similar *issue* like in [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/72482/5478) arises since coordinates are not well handled Mod360 wise. (I'm not 100% sure). But even then it would create line around so the real question is how to force geopath to find *geodesics* in opposite direction to real one.

Comment: I tried the fix from the quesiton you linked but unfortunately it made no difference.

Comment: The problem is that `GeoPath` is taking the _shorter_ route, and the top of your polygon is the longer route. I'm not sure how to convince it to take the longer route. I'll play with it.

Comment: The closing geodesic goes beyond the pole. An azimuthal projection would be more appropriate here: GeoGraphics[
 FilledCurve[{GeoPath[{{47, -75}, {-34, 18}, {40, 116}}, 
    CurveClosed -> True]}], 
 GeoProjection -> {"LambertAzimuthal", "Centering" -> {90, 0}}, 
 GeoRange -> "World", GeoGridLines -> Automatic]

Comment: This problem also occurs with `GeoCircle` in combination with some `GeoProjection`s, for example `"Orthographic"`.

Comment: [72476](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72476/geographics-problem-with-geoposition-in-shifted-projections) has a [tag:bugs] tag. Is this a bug too?