# Why does the GeoGraphics Frame show different Latitude than GeoPosition?

Tags: geography, geodesy, projection, geographics

The map looks right, but the Latitude in the `Frame` looks wrong.

Am I making a mistake or is this a bug?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is not a bug. When dealing with a map there are two different coordinate systems you need to handle, related by the cartographic projection you are using.

First you have the `{lat, lon}` coordinates on the surface of the Earth's ellipsoidal model. These are the numbers in `GeoPosition[{lat, lon}]`.

Then you have the coordinate `{x, y}` on the flat map of the Earth. These are the numbers in `GeoGridPosition[{x, y}, projection]`. The projection specifies the function that converts from `{lat, lon}` to `{x, y}` or viceversa. When you do `GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[{lat, lon}], projection]` you get `GeoGridPosition[{x, y}, projection]`. If you wrap the latter with `GeoPosition`, you get `GeoPosition[{lat, lon}]` back. The `"Equirectangular"` projection is basically defined as `x = lon, y = lat`. But other projections (say `"Mercator"`) have nontrivial formulas.

The map needs to use the map coordinates, that is {x, y}, and that is way your "Mercator" map does not agree with the expected {lat, lon} coordinates.

Comment: I agree, maybe should've stressed what is supposed to be reported to WRI - documentation with gaps.

Comment: I'm confused. Isn't Mercator latitude codomain supposed to be [-Pi, Pi]? They are rescaling it to Degree which makes no sense (for me) and is confusing (for me). What do you think?

Comment: The latitude phi range [-Pi, Pi] is mapped into Mercator y coordinate range [-Infinity, Infinity]. The transformation is y = Log[Tan[phi/2 + Pi/4]]. It is traditional in map webservers to show only the {x, y} square [-Pi, Pi] x [-Pi, Pi] of Mercator space, which corresponds to about [-85, 85] degrees in latitude. This means that Mercator maps do not show the geo disks of about 5 degrees radius around the poles, but that is not a big problem because around the North pole there is mostly water and around the South pole it is all ice. That is why GeoGraphics uses "Equirectangular" for world maps.

Comment: The question of whether to use radians or degrees is a different discussion. This is controlled by the "ReferenceModel" parameter of the projections. Try GeoProjectionData["Mercator"] and you will see the rescaling 180/Pi to convert to degrees, but something like "Albers" has model 1. The Geo functionality in the WL is degree-oriented, as determined by the main object, GeoPosition. The decision was to rescale back to degrees the cylindrical projections only, because for them the x projected coordinate is proper longitude. This was done to preserve most of the conventions of CountryData.

Answer (score 11):

To long for a comment:

It seems that `Geo-FrameTicks` are not handled well unless we use `"Equirectangular"` `GeoProjection`. Even if it is a [cylindrical projection](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CylindricalProjection.html), as a `"Mercator"` used here, the result's ticks seem to be rescaled badly.

I can't find anything about that in documentation so I'm encouraging you to report that to WRI Support.

Meanwhile use `"Equirectangular"` projection if you need ticks:

```
GeoGraphics[ GeoPosition @ {42.31, -71.19}, 
  GeoGridLines  -> Automatic, 
  Frame         -> True, 
  GeoProjection -> "Equirectangular",
  GeoRange      -> Quantity[10, "Miles"]
]
```

[image]

If you need different projections you can create custom `FrameTicks` (notice that GeogridLines are correct anyway) like I did in: [GeoProjection for astronomical data - wrong ticks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89792/5478)

[image]