# Getting GeoGraphis to Respect GeoRange

Tags: geographics

I am trying to create a baseline map for plotting some localities.  The following code almost gets me there, but I can not figure out how to get Geographics to respect the GeoRange specified.  Other questions on SE suggest there can be problems with any map projection other than Equirectangular.  However, this should not be an issue here.  (replace the *'d names that fall within the GeoRange with their entities).[Ignore the thick black lines, as I posted the image before creating a new one with thin lines]

How can the following code be modified to do so?

```
 ClearAll;
 GeoGraphics[{{GeoProjecction->"Equirectangular", GeoStyling["ReliefMap",
 GeoRange-> {{2,30},{60,95}}, GeoRangePadding->None, EdgeForm[{Thin,Black}],
 {Polygon[*India],Polygon[*Maldives],Polygon[*SriLanka],Polygon[*Pakistan],
 Polygon[*Nepal],Polygon[*China],Polygon[*Bangladesh],Polygon[*Afghanistan],
 Polygon[*Iran],Polygon[*Myanmar],Polygon[*Bhutan],Polygon[*Oman],
 Polygon[*Indonesia]}}, GeoBackground-> "ReliefMap",Frame->True]
```

[image]

Comment: Please convert your code to InputForm and then copy and paste that here so we won't have to do the tedious conversion to entities ourselves. See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951).

Comment: Have you tried passing `GeoRange` as an option to the `GeoGraphics` itself, eg after `Frame->True`?

Comment: Yes, this does work to get the correct GeoRange (as noted below)..  However, the frame units are graphic grid coordinates rather than the expected latitudes and longitudes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer based on Carl Lange's suggestion and following MarcoB's copy paste link. I followed the examples at [Wolfram: GeoGraphics](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoGraphics.html), that is

```
GeoGraphics[
{
Polygon[Entity["Country", #]]&/@{
"India", "Maldives", "Pakistan", "Nepal", "China", "Bangladesh", "Afghanistan", "Iran", "Bhutan", "Oman", "Indonesia"}
    }, 
  GeoBackground -> "ReliefMap",
  GeoProjection->"Equirectangular",
GeoGridLines->True, 
GeoRange->{{-5,45},{50,110}},
Frame-> True]
```

[image: Map w many countries but limited by GeoRange]

To me it seems like the lat-long is correct with the default projection.

UPDATE:Added all countries.  Framticks with Lat-Long seem to require that you use "Equirectangular" (see this post [GeoGraphics Frametics..](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/116507/why-does-the-geographics-frame-show-different-latitude-than-geoposition)).

The way I understand the rendering is that the first parameter of GeoGraphics is drawn "on top" of the canvas defined by the options. In your code, the limiting GeoRange is overridden by drawing the countries. If you add the limits as an option for the whole function, it seems to work.

Comment: That worked just fine, but still don't understand why the previous code did not.  However, adding Frames->True to see the Lat-Long on the boundary does not work and only gives values expressed as positive or negative percentages of deviation from the plot centered at (0,0).

Comment: Here is a source for how to add ticks for other projections, see https://sites.psu.edu/charlesammon/2017/04/15/adding-frameticks-to-maps-with-mathematica/

Comment: Yes.  Thank you for setting me straight with regard to the order of preference for the options.  Option ordering/nesting is a subtle issue that I had failed to appreciate.