# How do I increase the readability of this code?

Tags: programming, syntax, coding-style

Below is some code I am working on; being a beginner. How can I increase the readability of the part behind Manipulate?

I can't read my own code anymore, because it is simply too long and unordered. I don't know where a function ends and where the next one begins. What are tips to increase the readability of code? Are there some general principles or tricks in Mathematica I can use?

Please also share obvious tips, since I am just a beginner and still have to learn much...

```
f[y_] = 1/4 y (3 - y);
solution = DSolve[{y'[t] == f[y[t]], y[0] == c}, y[t], t][[1]];
ϕ[t_] = y[t] /. solution;

Manipulate[
 Row[{Show[
    VectorPlot[{1, f[y]}, {t, -8, 8}, {y, -4, 4},
     VectorStyle -> {Thick, Red}, VectorScale -> {.04, 1.5, None},
     VectorPoints -> 20],
    Plot[ϕ[t] /. c -> y0, {t, -8, b},
     PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}], Frame -> False, Axes -> True,
    AxesStyle -> Thick,
    AxesLabel -> {Text[Style["t", Black, Large, Italic]],
      Text[Style["y", Black, Large, Italic]]},
    TicksStyle -> {{Large, Black}, {Large, Black}},
    ImageSize -> Medium],
   Show[Plot[f[y], {y, -1, 4}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Orange},
     AxesLabel -> {Text[Style["y", Large, Italic]],
       Text[Style["f(y)", Large, Italic]]}, ImageSize -> Medium],
    Graphics[{Red, PointSize[.03],
      Point[{ϕ[b] /. c -> y0, 0}]}]]}], {b, -7.99,
  8}, {{y0, 2}, -1, 4}, LabelStyle -> Large]
```

With special thanks to Bill Kinney: *[Using Mathematica for Ordinary Differential Equations (ODEs)](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLmU0FIlJY-MlfXdrINHtYvBJINVIfQu7z)*

Comment: That is good question but it may be too "opinion based" for SE. You can take a look here: [**89792**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89792/5478) to see what I'm usually doing, also, writing in "Code" cells allows you to indent lines more consistently.

Comment: It's hard to tell why you find the code unreadable without seeing how you formatted it originally.

Comment: p.s. keep in mind that `VectorPlot` and the second `Plot` can be evaluated outside `Manipulate` and inserted in `Show`, otherwise you are recreating them each time.

Comment: I agree with @kuba, but I think this is a very important question.  In my experience, a major barrier on the Mathematica learning curve is code readability, which is further compounded by the automatic indenting/formatting performed by the Notebook front end.  General code-readability strategies, resisting use of greek symbols and sub/superscripts are all topics that pop up here, but to my knowledge they have not been localized in one Q&A.

Comment: @Kuba It is done!

Comment: @Kuba Thanks for the tip on the vectorplot; it should be outside manipulate. The second plot should be inside though.

Comment: related: [**Granular vs terse coding**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/110067/5478) p.s. @ImreVégh to be more precise, it should be outside of manipulate body, unless you use nested `Dynamic` to prevent unnecessary evaluation. Moreover, completely outside may not be the best place because one may need to have this definition preserved across FE sessions. Possible solutions are: `SaveDefinitions` or  defining it in `Initialization` or injecting that graphics with `With`.

Comment: If you are interested in tracking different variables, you might be interested in [How to change the font color of a variable in whole input cell](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89507/how-to-change-the-font-color-of-a-variable-in-whole-input-cell)

Comment: You should ask on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).  Learning to make code more readable is the entire purpose of that site.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I appear to be in the minority but I never write big blocks of *Mathematica* code, it's just too difficult to read. The way I look at it you have to consider how a reader will understand your app. So I make the main block very small, like this:

```
Manipulate[
 Row[{
   vectorPlotAndTrajectory[y0, b],
   Show[fy, position[y0, b]]
   }]
 , {b, -7.99, 8}
 , {{y0, 2}, -1, 4}
 , LabelStyle -> Large
 ]
```

The idea is that from this block the reader will be able to understand what the app is. There is a row with two figures, the left one is a vector plot with a trajectory and the right one is a function curve with something marked on it. If they want to understand further they can look up the individual definitions. So they go and look up `vectorPlotAndTrajectory` and they see

```
vectorPlotAndTrajectory[y0_, b_] := Show[
  vectorPlot, trajectory[y0, b]
  , Frame -> False, Axes -> True
  , AxesStyle -> Thick
  , AxesLabel -> {
    Text[Style["t", Black, Large, Italic]],
    Text[Style["y", Black, Large, Italic]]
    }
  , TicksStyle -> {{Large, Black}, {Large, Black}}
  , ImageSize -> Medium
  ]
```

Ah, so this is just the combination of a vector plot `vectorPlot` and a trajectory `trajectory`. So in order to understand even better they go to the definition of `vectorPlot`:

```
vectorPlot = VectorPlot[
   {1, f[y]}, {t, -8, 8}, {y, -4, 4}
   , VectorStyle -> {Thick, Red}
   , VectorScale -> {.04, 1.5, None}
   , VectorPoints -> 20
   ];
```

You get the idea. No one so far has suggested that you put the commas in the beginning of the line either, which I think really helps with the readability if there are three or more arguments.

If you really need it to be a single code block in the end there are meta programming techniques that can be used to generate such a code block; just because you need such an end result does not mean you have to look at the bestiality while developing the app. Just like when web developers write CSS they usually write it in LESS and the compile it to CSS, they don't have to look at the actual CSS!

Comment: Commas in the beginning also help to quickly comment in and out parts of the code on one line.

Comment: Commas at the beginning of the line makes me want to scratch my eyes out, but I can see the logic.

Comment: If I run your code it doesn't work...

Comment: @ImreVégh You don't have all the definitions, you don't have the definitions for `trajectory`, `fy` and `position` for example. It was not necessary to post the entire program to get my point across. It might be good practice to write the rest!

Comment: @SimonWoods I used to feel the same way, but after seeing WReach use this a number of times I am starting to use it myself, though not predominantly.  I suppose it's a bit like ~infix~: tangible superiority if you are comfortable with it, and nauseating if you are not. :^)

Comment: @C.E. Incidentally I only saw this Q&A now but you basically wrote the answer I would have had I seen it sooner.

Comment: I like your idea to work with a main block. Doesn't that imply though that the main block has to be the final part of the code, after all variables are defined? I would like the main block to be the first part of the whole code. Is that also possible?

Comment: @GambitSquared You can make a delayed definition such as ´start := Manipulate[...]´ and then put ´start´ wherever it is you want your code to be evaluated. That way, the code can still be read from the top down except now the reader has to locate where the app starts by first going to the bottom of the file, that has not changed. Packages can help in structuring code since then you can put your definitions in one file, load the definitions and use them from another.

Answer (score 19):

### Description

In software engineering, it is a good practice to comment your code. I would advise you to utilise comments to partition your code in a following way. Additionally, if you have ever worked with any other programming languages, you could employ indentation. Alternatively, you could modularize your application as to develop it in smaller, more manageable "chunks". Please see sample below

### Example #1 - Indentation + Comments (Full Program)

**Code**

```
f[y_] = 1/4 y (3 - y);
solution = DSolve[{y'[t] == f[y[t]], y[0] == 1}, y[t], t][[1]];
ϕ[t_] = y[t] /. solution;

Manipulate[
 Grid[
  Show[
   (*Show Component Declaration*)

   VectorPlot[
    (*Vector Plot Declaration*)
    {1, f[y]}, {t, -8, 8}, {y, -4, 4},
    (*Vector Plot Options*)
    VectorStyle -> {Thick, Red},
    VectorScale -> {.04, 1.5, None},
    VectorPoints -> 20
    ],

   Plot[
    (*Plot Declaration*)
    ϕ[t] /. c -> y0, {t, -8, b},
    (*Plot Option Declaration*)
    PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}
    ],

   (*Show Option Declaration*)
   Frame -> False,
   Axes -> True,
   AxesStyle -> Thick, 
   AxesLabel -> {Text[Style["t", Black, Large, Italic]], 
     Text[Style["y", Black, Large, Italic]]}, 
   TicksStyle -> {{Large, Black}, {Large, Black}}, ImageSize -> Medium
   ],

  Show[
   (*Show Component Declaration*)
   Plot[
    (*Plot Declaration*)
    f[y], {y, -1, 4},
    (*Plot Option Declaration*)
    PlotStyle -> {Thick, Orange}, 
    AxesLabel -> {Text[Style["y", Large, Italic]], 
      Text[Style["f(y)", Large, Italic]]}, ImageSize -> Medium],

   Graphics[
    (*Graphics Component Declaration*)
    {Red, PointSize[.03], Point[{ϕ[b] /. c -> y0, 0}]}
    ]
   ]
  ],
 (*Manipulate Control Declaration*)
 {b, -7.99, 8}, 
 {{y0, 2}, -1, 4},
 (*Manipulate Option Declaration*)
 LabelStyle -> Large
 ]
```

### Example #2 - Indentation + Comments + Modularization (Sample)

**Code**

```
DynamicModule[
 {
  c, y, f,
  y0 = 2,
  b = 1,
  solution, \[Phi],
  plotVector, plotPlot
  },

 (*Input/Output Description*)
 f[y_] := 1/4 y (3 - y);

 (*Input/Output Description*)
 solution = DSolve[{y'[t] == f[y[t]], y[0] == c}, y[t], t][[1]];

 (*Input/Output Description*)
 \[Phi][t_] := y[t] /. solution;

 (*Main Column*)
 Panel @ Column[{
    (*Output Description*)
    Row @ {
      Dynamic @ Show[{
         (*Output Description*)
         plotVector = VectorPlot[{1, f[y]}, {t, -8, 8}, {y, -4, 4}, VectorStyle -> {Thick, Red}, VectorScale -> {.04, 1.5, None}, VectorPoints -> 20];
         (*Output Description*)
         plotPlot = Plot[\[Phi][t] /. c -> y0, {t, -8, b}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}];

         plotVector,
         plotPlot
         },
        (*Show Options*)
        Frame -> False, Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Thick, 
        AxesLabel -> {Text[Style["t", Black, Large, Italic]], Text[Style["y", Black, Large, Italic]]}, TicksStyle -> {{Large, Black}, {Large, Black}}, 
        ImageSize -> Medium
        ]
      },

    (*Output Description*)
    Column @ {
      Row @ {Style["y0 ", 16], Slider[Dynamic @ y0, {-1, 4}]},
      Row @ {Style["b", 16], Slider[Dynamic @ b, { -7.99, 8}]}
      }
    },
   (*Main Column Options*)
   Alignment -> Center]
 ]
```

### Notes

**N.1** It is always a good idea to give your variables a descriptive name. Given that I am not aware what you are trying to solve, I left variable names as in OP and any additional variables been given dummy names which ***SHOULD*** be changed

**N.2** I wanted to move both `plotVector` and `plotPlot1` definition outside `Show`, but couldn't figure out how to introduce `Dynamic` updating of `plotPlot1` in this configuration*)

Comment: I will edit this post in an hour or so

Comment: I wouldn't completely agree on your first statement: there is quite some debate about how much and which kind of comments are useful in code. To my understanding one of the current "mainstream" opinions to the subject is that your code should as much as possible document itself, no documentation is better than outdated documentation and you should not "state the obvious". Plese don't get it the wrong way, I like your style (less dense than most alternatives) but I find most of your comments to  be of the "state the obvious" category which probably doesn't help to understand the code very much.

Comment: Just to mention: I also completely agree on what you say about indentation and modularization...

Comment: @AlbertRetey with regards to comments, I agree with what you wrote. In a perfect world we would be able to declare our variables, arguments, parameters, functions and methods in such way where you wouldn't require giving an excessive amount of comments to describe the purpose of the code we write

Comment: @AlbertRetey Also, perhaps, a better word for the comments above would be a "tag". I use them in such a way in order to identify the scope I work in

Comment: @AlbertRetey, I also would like to mention that if one really, really want to put in a comment (and one should try hard not to) then it should answer the question of 'why' something was done not 'what' was done - One has to assume that the reader of the code can read the language. A better alternative to comments are asserts - as they are part of the program.

Comment: @E.Doroskevic: I see your point with using these comments as tags. Still when you need those, that might be an indication that you are trying to do too much in one function/cell/expression. I probably should also mention that I wouldn't consider myself as a strict advocate for the "avoid comments in any case" guidline, but I see a point in it and think the statement about good practice was in need of a counterstatement. I like the notes you added to your answer.

Comment: @user21: I guess you have already read at least some of them, but of course any potential reader of answers to this question should make sure to have at least a quick look into one of the classics (?) about the topic, e.g. "clean code" or "pragmatic programmer". I also liked "Weniger schlecht programmieren", just for the title :-). Even if you decide to not agree with every point the authors make and some of their finings might not apply to Mathematica, you'll at least get an idea why writing clean code makes sense and learn to recognize the decisions you implicitly make...

Comment: @AlbertRetey I appreciate that and agree with you on this subject matter. I will improve this post over time and include guidelines and notes describing the way I write code using wolfram language

Comment: Have you tried := for plotVector? Anyways, I like Row@{}, saves one pair of braces over Row[{}]. I started using @ whenever it reduces the total amount of characters or nesting, even if just by one.

Answer (score 13):

Personally, I use lots of newlines and let the Front End indent.  There doesn't seem to be anything special in your code, other than a lot of nesting that is in fact necessary in this case.

[image]

You were using `Grid` incorrectly.  `Grid[a,b]` is wrong.  `Grid[{{a,b}}]` or `Grid[{{a},{b}}]` are correct.   I guess you wanted `Column[{a,b}]`, so I changed that.

Using `Text` in `AxesLabel` is unusual and unnecessary. You can remove that.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the way it would look if it were my code.My formatting style is much the same as Szabolcs' (including replacing your grid with a column), but I don't like his dangling `]`, and you won't see those. Also, I **always** start control specifications on a new line, and I mostly start option specifications on a new line, too.

[image: code]

Note: I have redefined ϕ to accept a parameter `c`. This is to make sense of your 2nd control `y0`, but I am not sure I have got it right. That is, I am not entirely sure my `c` is the parameter you intended to vary with the `y0` control.

Answer (score 4):

Is this a "standard" `Manipulate` which will not grow larger? Ok, use one of already posted answers.

Here is an alternative in case where `Manipulate` is supposed to be generated from a package function or is a part of a bigger code.

```
ClearAll["Test`*"];

BeginPackage["Test`"]

    myManipulate::usage = "myManipulate[] generates a demo Manipulate";

Begin["`Private`"]

    myManipulate[]:= Panel @ DynamicModule[{ϕ, b = -.7, y0 = 2}, 
        fiGeneration[ϕ, 2];
        Column[{
            Row[{ leftShow[b, ϕ], rightShow[b, ϕ] }], 

            LabeledSlider[Dynamic[b], {-7.99, 8}], 
            LabeledSlider[Dynamic[y0, (y0=#;fiGeneration[ϕ, y0]) &], {-1, 4}]
        }]
    ];

    SetAttributes[fiGeneration, HoldFirst];
    fiGeneration[ϕ_, y0_]:= Block[{solution, t, y},
        solution =  DSolve[{y'[t] == f[y[t]], y[0] == y0}, y[t], t][[1]];
        ϕ[t_] = y[t] /. solution;

    ];

    SetAttributes[{leftShow,rightShow}, HoldAll];

    leftShow[b_, ϕ_]:= With[{
        vectorPlot = fVectorPlot[]
        },
        Dynamic @ Show[
            vectorPlot , 
            fiPlot[b, ϕ] , 
            Frame -> False, Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Thick, 
            AxesLabel -> {
                Text[Style["t", Black, Large, Italic]], 
                Text[Style["y", Black, Large, Italic]]
            }, 
            TicksStyle -> {{Large, Black}, {Large, Black}}, 
            ImageSize -> Medium, Background->White
    ]];

    SetAttributes[fiPlot,HoldAll];
    fiPlot[b_, ϕ_]:=Plot[ϕ[t] , {t, -8, b}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}];



    rightShow[b_, ϕ_]:= With[{plot =  fPlot[]},
        Show[
            plot, 
            Graphics[{Red, PointSize[.03], Dynamic @ Point[{ϕ[b], 0}]}]
        ]
    ];

    f[y_]:= 1/4 y (3 - y);

    fPlot[]:=Plot[ f[y], {y, -1, 4}, 
        PlotStyle -> {Thick, Orange},   
        AxesLabel -> {
            Text[Style["y", Large, Italic]], 
            Text[Style["f(y)", Large, Italic]]
        }, 
        ImageSize -> Medium
    ];

    fVectorPlot[]:=VectorPlot[
        {1, f[y]}, {t, -8, 8}, {y, -4, 4}, 
        VectorStyle -> {Thick, Red}, 
        VectorScale -> {.04, 1.5, None}, 
        VectorPoints -> 20
    ];



End[];
EndPackage[];
```

I can create two instances of `myManipulate[]` and they won't interfere even though they share definitions of `leftShow` etc. That's because what is important is scoped in `DynamicModule`:

```
myManipulate[]

myManipulate[]
```

[image]

It's not better approach but sometimes it is useful. You may want to add `SaveDefinitions` because some of definitions are not going to be stored. But I didn't because the package may be loaded by `Initialization` preventing duplication of definitions in many instances of `DynamicModule`. What to do really depends of the case.