# Mollweide Projection of a Sphere

Tags: plotting, geographics, geodesy

I want to recreate the following picture [image]

for a project. However, I am not sure how to do this with Mathematica. Is there an easy way to obtain just the "background" picture of the sphere without the data that appear with blue and red colors and add the data later on through a list?

Thank you in advance

---

Wow I have indeed missed these very useful posts. Thank you very much! I have on extra question. I have constructed the following list of datapoints

```
list={{0.000114589, 122.672, 26.1591}, {0.000116848, 123.48,29.4959}, {0.000168035, 122.847, 26.8044}, {0.000257776, 123.345,28.8847}, {0.000502939, 123.558, 29.6776}, {0.000580785, 123.256,28.479}}{0.000470642, 122.588, 25.4321}, {0.0000279161, 123.541, 29.7422},{0.000206893, 122.682, 26.0995}, {0.000188516, 122.573, 25.5085}, {0.000429472, 123.571, 29.7051}, {0.000278518, 123.831, 30.3842},{0.000347686, 123.479, 29.5709}, {0.000211741, 123.62, 29.8788}, {0.000326793, 123.163, 28.0487}, {5.58289*10^-6, 123.067, 27.67}, {0.000131174, 122.509, 25.5254}, {0.000666323, 122.579, 25.6588}, {0.000189534, 123.647, 30.1039}, {0.000185758, 123.543, 29.4141},{0.0000900875, 123.398, 29.1022}, {0.0000658898, 122.893, 26.8988}, {0.000269479, 122.543, 25.3957}, {0.0000897253, 122.873, 26.8974};
```

Say I want the first element of each sublist to be coloured differently (the 2nd and 3rd elements correspond to the galactic coordinates of some supernovae). How can I construct the GeoGraphic plot of these points with an appropriate barlegend indicating the colour of each of the first elements?

Comment: Yes, try `GeoGraphics`. Here is one example: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72426/5478

Comment: Maybe not really a duplicate. But certainly a relevant link. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13361/mollweide-maps-in-mathematica

Comment: About your edit, notice that in the linked example I do exactly that, the third column is used to specify colors of points.

Comment: Yes you are right. However I would also like to have a barlegend which will show the value of a third variable. For example the first element of each sublist in my edit. Thank you very much for your time. I am fairly new to Mathematica and I am a little bit confused!

Comment: You can add one with BarLegend.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments and your time! I will try it out.