# How to plot a vector field on a geographic map?

Tags: plotting, geographics

Suppose I want to `VectorPlot` on a geographic map a vector field defined on a Reference Ellipsoid.

The field is given to the following function as a `f_` (or `{fx_, fy_}`) whose two components are the latitudinal and longitudinal components.

Following the approach I used to `ContourPlot` a scalar field I can end with a code like this:

```
SetAttributes[GeoGraphicsVectorPlot, HoldAll]
Options[GeoGraphicsVectorPlot] = {
   "GeoGraphicsOptions" -> {},
   "PlotCellsCount" -> 10000
   };
SyntaxInformation[
   GeoGraphicsContourPlot] = {"LocalVariables" -> {"Solve", {2, 2}}};

GeoGraphicsVectorPlot[f_, gcoords : {Repeated[_Symbol, {3}]}, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Module[{geog, datum, proj, geogpol, mesh, coords, vlp, vlc, fl, fail,
    pvl, plotType, plotOptions, plot, plotPrimitives},

  geog = GeoGraphics[{}, OptionValue["GeoGraphicsOptions"]];
  {datum, proj} = {GeoModel, GeoProjection} /. 
    AbsoluteOptions[geog, {GeoModel, GeoProjection}];
  geogpol = 
   First@Cases[geog, 
     Polygon[vl_, ___, VertexTextureCoordinates -> _, ___] :> 
      Polygon@vl, \[Infinity]];
  mesh = DiscretizeRegion[geogpol, 
    MaxCellMeasure -> Area@geogpol/OptionValue["PlotCellsCount"]];
  coords = MeshCoordinates[mesh];
  vlp = GeoGridPosition[coords, proj, datum];
  vlc = GeoPositionXYZ[vlp];
  fl = With[{n = Length@gcoords}, 
    Map[Block[gcoords, gcoords = Take[#, n]; f] &, vlc[[1]]]];
  pvl = Transpose@{coords, fl};
  pvl = adjustVectorField[proj, datum] /@ pvl;
  plot = ListVectorPlot[pvl];
  MapAt[{{#}, plot[[1]]} &, Graphics @@ geog, {1}] 
  ]

adjustVectorField[proj_, datum_] := Identity

GeoGraphicsVectorPlot[{1, 2}, {x, y, z},
 "GeoGraphicsOptions" -> {GeoRange -> "World", GeoModel -> "GRS80", 
   GeoProjection -> "Mercator"}]

GeoGraphicsVectorPlot[{1, 2}, {x, y, z},
 "GeoGraphicsOptions" -> {GeoRange -> "World", GeoModel -> "GRS80", 
   GeoProjection -> "Equirectangular"}]
```

The tricky part, with respect to the scala field, is how to properly compute the projected direction of the field, i.e. how to define the family of functions `adjustVectorField[proj_, datum_]` so that it works on many (ideally all) map projections.

Comment: just leaving a link: [**13411**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13411/5478)

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure if I got the point, is this what you are after?

```
gr2 = StreamPlot[{-1 - Sin[x]^2 + Sin[3 y] + Cos[y]^2, 
   1 + Sin[2 x] - Cos[y]^2}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/2, Frame -> False, 
  StreamColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors", StreamPoints -> 250]
```

> [image]

```
GeoGraphics[
 First @ gr2 /. Arrow -> (Arrow @ GeoPath[Reverse[#, {2}] / Degree, "Rhumb"]&)
 ,
 GeoRange -> "World",
 GeoProjection -> "LambertAzimuthal"]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Something like this, yes. But I have two problems: 1) my field is defined in term of XYZ coords, not lat/long; 2) the stream lines are well distributed and well segmented in the preliminary graphic but in some projection (for example Mercator) become very distant and with segments very long near the poles. My tentative to work in the projected domain was to avoid this.

Comment: @unlikely I see, so you want the distribution uniform. What about arrows lengths, should the same magnitude near pole for Mercator be longer than near equator?

Comment: Not sure to understand your question...

Comment: @unlikely p.s. when I use `GeoGraphicsVectorPlot[{x, y} // Normalize, {x, y, z},` it doesn't look right, unless I'm missing something, but `VectorPlot[{x, y} // Normalize, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi/2, Pi/2}` is ok.

Comment: @unlikely Arrows lengths are reflecting the magnitude of the field, when regions near poles are streched then those arrows will become longer which will reflect intensity but maybe you want {1,1} vector to be the same length on differently stretched regions, like in your example.

Comment: My idea was just to get a "nice" (uniform, well segmented) plot. But I understand what you means. And you are right, with "my" approach, I expect that a constant magnitude vector field is plotted with equal length arrows everywhere. Your idea to stretch the arrow length according to the stretching of the map does also make sense, particularly if the field represent something length-related.

Comment: I don't know what is better or if there is some convention or accepted standard. I think that "my" approach, while maybe not as correct as yours, make easier to immediately understand where the field is more intense, without having to mentally deduct the effect of map stretching. What do you think? Maybe we can resort to use a `StreamPlot` like you did just to avoid this possible ambiguity.

Comment: @unlikely both are ok, depends what is needed. Your is probably  more intuitive. Just wanted to clarify your needs.

Comment: Any idea to accomplish this?